# How to change the status bar color in Android?

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-statusbar

First of all it's not a duplicate as in [How to change the background color of android status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044970/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-android-status-bar)

How do I change the status bar color which should be same as in navigation bar.

I want the status bar color to be same as the navigation bar color

[image]

Comment: it is possible only after kitkat @MarkBuikema

Comment: As Niels suggests, there is a THEME ATTRIBUTE since v21 called `android:statusBarColor`. You can simply add it to `values-v21/styles.xml`.

Comment: @MarkBuikema How's that even related to root access!

Comment: Have a look at  [this answer(Make the status bar white with black icons).](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74375368/2289835)

Answer (score 449, accepted):

Update:

Lollipop:

```
public abstract void setStatusBarColor (int color)
```

Added in API level 21

Android Lollipop brought with it the ability to change the color of status bar in your app for a more immersive user experience and in tune with Google’s `Material Design Guidelines`.

Here is how you can change the color of the status bar using the new `window.setStatusBarColor` method introduced in **`API level 21`**.

Changing the color of status bar also requires setting two additional flags on the Window; you need to add the `FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS` flag and clear the `FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS` flag.

Working Code:

```
import android.view.Window;
```

...

```
Window window = activity.getWindow();

// clear FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag:
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

// add FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS flag to the window
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

// finally change the color
window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity,R.color.my_statusbar_color));
```

Offcial developer reference : [setStatusBarColor(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setStatusBarColor(int))

Example :[material-design-everywhere](http://antonioleiva.com/material-design-everywhere/)

[Chris Banes Blog- appcompat v21: material design for pre-Lollipop devices!](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/)

[image]

The `transitionName` for the view background will be `android:status:background`.

Comment: As noted in the answer by Niels: you can also configure the status bar color via theme/style by setting `android:statusBarColor` in your `values-v21/styles.xml` file per http://www.androiddocs.com/training/material/theme.html like so `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primary_color</item>`

Comment: i can change the status bar color to white, but i can't see the notification icon like batery, how can i solve this?

Comment: How to undo this please?

Answer (score 799):

Android 5.0 Lollipop introduced Material Design theme which automatically colors the status bar based on the `colorPrimaryDark` value of the theme.

> Note by realdognose: with Material Design library it will be `colorPrimaryVariant`

This is supported on device pre-lollipop thanks to the library support-v7-appcompat starting from version 21. [Blogpost about support appcompat v21 from Chris Banes](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/)

[image]

[Read more about the Material Theme on the official Android Developers website](https://developer.android.com/preview/material/theme.html)

Comment: in some reason colorPrimaryDark attribute doesnt work for me. tried on emulator v21

Comment: It works you have to see the changes on the emulator not on the layout preview[it doesn't show there]

Comment: colorPrimaryDark isn't working for me either on an API 18 emulator. From the article linked about appcompat: "On older platforms, AppCompat emulates the color theming where possible. At the moment this is limited to coloring the action bar and some widgets."

Comment: What about changing the **font** color in the status bar?  The docs don't say anything about that.

Comment: I tried the same way. it works perfectly in most of all devices, but i have samsung galaxy s4 running OS 5.0.1 and in this phone status bar color is black. And once i go to another activity and comes again to previous activity my status bar color is changed to app theme color. Any reason why this is happening

Comment: Now in `themes.xml` it wil be `colorPrimaryVariant` instead of `colorPrimaryDark`

Comment: What if I want it to be `windowBackground` when no action bar theme is set? I don't want to do it programatically.

Comment: "This is supported on device pre-lollipop "  @Giorgio obviously means "POST-lollipop" as this is only supported on SDKs AFTER lollipop ...

Answer (score 301):

Place this is your `values-v21/styles.xml`, to enable this on Lollipop:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_secondary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/color_primary</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: this requires min API 21

Comment: This is probably why he suggested to put it into values-v21/styles.xml ;-) Seems to be the most accurate answer so far!!

Comment: But this still flags a warning!!?

Comment: what is the function for compat? status bar

Comment: you can add `targeApi` attribute if you want to maintain a single style file. Read my answer for reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/48565459/4291272

Answer (score 61):

**For Java Developers:**

As @Niels said you have to place in values-v21/styles.xml:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/black</item>
```

But add `tools:targetApi="lollipop"` if you want single styles.xml, like:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/black</item>
```

**For Kotlin Developers:**

```
window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color_name)
```

Answer (score 51):

You can use this simple code:

**One-liner in Kotlin:**

```
window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorName)
```

**Original answer with Java & manual version check:**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccentDark_light, this.getTheme()));
} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccentDark_light));
}
```

Answer (score 50):

this is very easy way to do this without any Library:
if the OS version is not supported - under kitkat - so nothing happend.
i do this steps:

1. in my xml i added to the top this View:

> ```
> <View
>         android:id="@+id/statusBarBackground"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
> ```

then i made this method:

```
 public void setStatusBarColor(View statusBar,int color){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
           Window w = getWindow();
           w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
           //status bar height
           int actionBarHeight = getActionBarHeight();
           int statusBarHeight = getStatusBarHeight();
           //action bar height
           statusBar.getLayoutParams().height = actionBarHeight + statusBarHeight;
           statusBar.setBackgroundColor(color);
     }
}
```

also you need those both methods to get action Bar & status bar height:

```
public int getActionBarHeight() {
    int actionBarHeight = 0;
    TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
    if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true))
    {
       actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
    return actionBarHeight;
}

public int getStatusBarHeight() {
    int result = 0;
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return result;
}
```

then the only thing you need is this line to set status bar color:

```
setStatusBarColor(findViewById(R.id.statusBarBackground),getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
```

Comment: where should I put the view element? should it be on top of the main layout?

Comment: Yes. In your xml. At the top of it.

Comment: Caution : Working only for android >= 19 API. In my case I need support starting from 16

Comment: setStatusBarColor(findViewById(android.R.id.statusBarBackground),getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));

Answer (score 40):

To change the color for above lolipop just add this to your styles.xml

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/statusBarColor</item>
```

**but remember**, if you  want to have a light color for the status bar, add this line too

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

Comment: Truly startling that NOBODY else saw fit to include the bit about windowLightStatusBar. You can tell who the copy-paste artistes are. :-) Anyone who had actually done this would know about the glaring hole in the SDK documentation.

Answer (score 32):

Well, Izhar's solution was OK but personally, I try to avoid code that looks as this:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
//Do what you need for this SDK
};
```

But I don't like to duplicate code either. In your answer I have to add a line of code like below in all Activities:

```
setStatusBarColor(findViewById(R.id.statusBarBackground),getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
```

So, I took Izhar's solution and used XML to get the same result:
Create a layout for the StatusBar status_bar.xml

```
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/statusBarHeight"
     android:background="@color/primaryColorDark"
     android:elevation="@dimen/statusBarElevation">
```

Notice the height and elevation attributes, these will be set in values, values-v19, values-v21 further down.

Add this layout to your activities layout using include, main_activity.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/Black" >

<include layout="@layout/status_bar"/>
<include android:id="@+id/app_bar" layout="@layout/app_bar"/>
//The rest of your layout       
</RelativeLayout>
```

For the Toolbar, add top margin attribute:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/primaryColor"
app:theme="@style/MyCustomToolBarTheme"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
android:elevation="@dimen/toolbarElevation"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/appBarTopMargin"
android:textDirection="ltr"
android:layoutDirection="ltr">
```

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

In your appTheme style-v19.xml and styles-v21.xml, add the windowTranslucent attr:

styles-v19.xml, v21:

```
<resources>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</resources>
```

And finally, on your dimens, dimens-v19, dimens-v21, add the values for the Toolbar topMargin, and the height of the statusBarHeight:
dimens.xml for less than KitKat:

```
<resources>
<dimen name="toolbarElevation">4dp</dimen>
<dimen name="appBarTopMargin">0dp</dimen>
<dimen name="statusBarHeight">0dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

The status bar height is always 24dp
dimens-v19.xml for KitKat and above:

```
<resources>
<dimen name="statusBarHeight">24dp</dimen>
<dimen name="appBarTopMargin">24dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

dimens-v21.xml for Lolipop, just add the elevation if needed:

```
<resources>
<dimen name="statusBarElevation">4dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

This is the result for Jellybean KitKat and Lollipop:

[image]

Comment: So instead of putting the check in code, you've put it in XML. You solution will work on Kitkat, just like what he got.

Answer (score 26):

Just create a new theme in **res/values/styles.xml** where you change the "colorPrimaryDark" which is the color of the status bar:

```
<style name="AppTheme.GrayStatusBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorGray</item>
</style>
```

And modify the activity theme in **AndroidManifest.xml** to the one you want, on the next activity you can change the color back to the original one by selecting the original theme:

```
<activity
    android:name=".LoginActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.GrayStatusBar" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This is how your **res/values/colors.xml** should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#c6d6f0</color>
    <color name="colorGray">#757575</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: This didn't work when running on Nougat and api level set to 19. It did work if I set android:theme under the application node in the manifest.

Answer (score 20):

You can change the status bar color with this function. works on android L means API 21 and higher and needs a color string such as `"#ffffff"`.

```
private void changeStatusBarColor(String color){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor(color));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

To Change the color of the status bar go to 
`res/values-v21/styles.xml` and color of status bar

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_secondary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">#0000FF</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 15):

I had this requirement: **Changing programmatically the status bar color keeping it transparent**, to allow the Navigation Drawer to draw itself overlapping the trasparent status bar.

I cannot do that using the API

```
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity ,R.color.my_statusbar_color)
```

If you check here in stack overflow everyone before that line of code set the transparency of the status bar to solid with

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
```

I'm able to manage **color and transparency** of status bar like this:

- Android 4: there's not much you can do, because you can't manage status bar color from the API ... the only thing you can do is to set the status bar as translucent and move a colored element of you UI under the status bar. To do this you need to play with

  ```
  android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
  ```

  in your main layout. This allows you to draw you layout under the status bar. Then you need to play with some padding with the top of your main layout.
- Android 5 and above: you have to define a style with

  ```
  <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
  <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
  ```

  this allows the navigation drawer to overlap the status bar.

  Then to change the color keeping the status bar transparent you have to set the status bar color with

  ```
  drawerLayout.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.my_statusbar_color))
  ```

  where drawerLayout is defined like this

  ```
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
      android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
  ```

Answer (score 11):

If you want to change the status bar color programmatically (and provided the device has Android 5.0).
This is a simple way to change **statusBarColor** from any **Activity**
and very easy methods when differents **fragments** have different status bar color.

```
 /**
 * @param colorId id of color
 * @param isStatusBarFontDark Light or Dark color
 */
fun updateStatusBarColor(@ColorRes colorId: Int, isStatusBarFontDark: Boolean = true) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        val window = window
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
        window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, colorId)
        setSystemBarTheme(isStatusBarFontDark)
    }
}

/** Changes the System Bar Theme.  */
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private fun setSystemBarTheme(isStatusBarFontDark: Boolean) {
    // Fetch the current flags.
    val lFlags = window.decorView.systemUiVisibility
    // Update the SystemUiVisibility depending on whether we want a Light or Dark theme.
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = if (isStatusBarFontDark) lFlags and View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR.inv() else lFlags or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to work on Android 4.4 and above, try this. I refer to Harpreet's answer and this link. [Android and the transparent status bar](http://blog.raffaeu.com/archive/2015/04/11/android-and-the-transparent-status-bar.aspx)

First, call setStatusBarColored method in Activity's onCreate method(I put it in a util class). I use a image here, you can change it to use a color.

```
public static void setStatusBarColored(Activity context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    {
        Window w = context.getWindow();
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        int statusBarHeight = getStatusBarHeight(context);

        View view = new View(context);
        view.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        view.getLayoutParams().height = statusBarHeight;
        ((ViewGroup) w.getDecorView()).addView(view);
        view.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.navibg));
    }
}

public static int getStatusBarHeight(Activity context) {
    int result = 0;
    int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        result = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Before:
[image: before]

After:
[image: after]

The color of the status bar has been changed, but the navi bar is cut off, so we need to set the margin or offset of the navi bar in the onCreate method.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int)(this.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.navibar_height)));
        layoutParams.setMargins(0, Utils.getStatusBarHeight(this), 0, 0);

        this.findViewById(R.id.linear_navi).setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
```

Then the status bar will look like this.

[image: status bar]

Answer (score 7):

Edit the colorPrimary in the  colors.xml in Values to the color you want the Status Bar to be. For example:

```
   <resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#800000</color> // changes the status bar color to Burgundy
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
<color name="red">#FF0000</color>
<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="cream">#fffdd0</color>
<color name="burgundy">#800000</color>
```

Answer (score 6):

Solution is very Simple, put the following lines into your style.xml

**For dark mode:**

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/black</item>
```

Answer (score 6):

Just add these lines in your styles.xml file

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- This is used for statusbar color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <!-- This is used for statusbar content color. If statusbarColor is light, use "true" otherwise use "false"-->
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me in KitKat and with good results.

```
public static void setTaskBarColored(Activity context) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        {
            Window w = context.getWindow();
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            //status bar height
            int statusBarHeight = Utilities.getStatusBarHeight(context);

            View view = new View(context);
            view.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            view.getLayoutParams().height = statusBarHeight;
            ((ViewGroup) w.getDecorView()).addView(view);
            view.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryTaskBar));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

change the **colorPrimaryDark** to your desire color into the res/values/styles.xml file

```xml
    <resources>
        <color name="colorPrimary">#800000</color>
        <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color> //This Line
        <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
        <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
        <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
       <color name="cream">#fffdd0</color>
       <color name="burgundy">#800000</color>
    </resources>
```

Answer (score 3):

Java:
Use this in the onCreate Method of the Activity

```
Window window = this.getWindow();
window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.main_screen_bg_color));
```

Kotlin:

```
window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorName)
```

Answer (score 3):

For specific **activity only** use :

```
   Window window = this.getWindow();
   window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

or in kotlin

```
window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.red)
```

in onCreate of Activity.

For **entire application** update "colorPrimaryVariant" in themes.xml :

```
<style name="Theme.Demo" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/text_color</item>
        
        <!-- Primary brand color, used for status bar color   -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/red</item>
  </style>
```

Answer (score 3):

**2024 - using WindowInsetsControllerCompat**

> Provide simple controls of windows that generate insets. For SDKs >=
> 30, this class is a simple wrapper around WindowInsetsController. For
> lower SDKs, this class aims to behave as close as possible to the
> original implementation.

```kotlin
fun Activity.setSystemBarAppearance(
    statusBarColor: Int,
    navigationBarColor: Int,
    isAppearanceLightStatusBars: Boolean,
    isAppearanceLightNavigationBars: Boolean
) {
        window.statusBarColor = getColorInt(statusBarColor)
        window.navigationBarColor = getColorInt(navigationBarColor)
        val windowInsetController = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)
        windowInsetController.isAppearanceLightStatusBars = isAppearanceLightStatusBars
        windowInsetController.isAppearanceLightNavigationBars = isAppearanceLightNavigationBars
}
```

```kotlin
fun Context.getColorInt(id: Int) = ContextCompat.getColor(this, id)
```

**Reference**: [WindowInsetsControllerCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/WindowInsetsControllerCompat)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

One more solution:

```
final View decorView = w.getDecorView();
View view = new View(BaseControllerActivity.this);
final int statusBarHeight = UiUtil.getStatusBarHeight(ContextHolder.get());
view.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, statusBarHeight));
view.setBackgroundColor(colorValue);
((ViewGroup)decorView).addView(view);
```

Comment: whats 'w' and 'UiUtil' here?

Answer (score 2):

This solution only works on API >= 23.
In API level 30 setSystemUiVisibility() has been deprecated. Hence you should use WindowInsetsControllerCompat as follows

```
fun changeColorStatusBar(color: Int = R.color.white) {
        val window: Window = window
        val decorView = window.decorView
        val wic = WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, decorView)
        wic.isAppearanceLightStatusBars = true
        // And then you can set any background color to the status bar.
        window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, color)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

i used this code to change status bar to transparent

```
    activity?.window?.setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
    )
```

to change it to color in style used this code
i used in fragment in onDetach()

```
activity?.window?.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set a custom drawable file use this code snippet

```
fun setCustomStatusBar(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        val decor = window.decorView
        decor.viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(object :
            ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {
            override fun onPreDraw(): Boolean {
                decor.viewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(this)
                val statusBar = decor.findViewById<View> 
                  (android.R.id.statusBarBackground)
                statusBar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_statusbar)
                return true
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

`Notice:` set `colorPrimaryVariant`

Answer (score 1):

A very very old question. But for someone who wants to change status bar color from `ANDROID 5.0, API 21` & above according to `theme` `Dark` and `Light` even `Device DEFAULT`.
Put this code in your activity after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` and before `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

```
int currentNightMode = getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
    switch (currentNightMode) {
        case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
            // Night mode is not active on device
            // For WHITE status bar Icons color to dark
            Window window = getWindow();
            View view = window.getDecorView();
            new WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, view).setAppearanceLightStatusBars(true);
            break;
        case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
            // Night mode is active on device
            break;
    }
```

And also in your `style.xml`put this line
`<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorWhite</item>`

Comment: can't see any style.xml

Answer (score 1):

In the values/theme.xml, add the item that named `name="android:statusBarColor"`.

```
 <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
        <style name="Theme.YourAppName" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
            ...
            ...
            ...
            <!-- Status bar color. -->
            <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">@color/purple_700</item>
        </style>
    </resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call Method From Activity that you want to change status bar color.

```
blackIconStatusBar(this, R.color.white);
```

Method Defination

```
public static void blackIconStatusBar(Activity activity, int color) {

    activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    activity.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
    activity.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, color));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin I was able to resolve this using the following:

```
  window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
  window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.transparent)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Solution: after `lollipop version` this code works for add this in if
> and call this in `onCreate`

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = this.getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.blueColorPrimaryDark));
    }
```