# Android Material: Status bar color won't change

Tags: android, statusbar, material-design

I'm developing an simple app to test the material design. I'm using `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0` and my activity looks like:

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
   ...
}
```

The layout is defined as:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now i defined my theme following material guidelines:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark700</item>
</style>
```

I'd like to change the status bar color in pre Android 5 and set it to `colorPrimaryDark` but i can't find the way. I tried using:

```
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(..)
```

but setStatusBar color is available from level 21. 
Why if i define a `colorPrimaryDark` in my theme and use appcompact the status bar doesn't change color?
Anyone can help?

Comment: Seems like a bug in appcompat-v7. Would you mind filing an issue at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list/ so we can track it? Please include your layout and style XML in the issue. Thanks!

Comment: There should be WindowCompat methods for setStatusBarColor() as well. Feel free to mention that in the issue or file a separate issue.

Comment: Thx alanv for your answer. I will investigate more on this issue checking if i made something wrong and if i can't find the way i will open the issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Status Bar Color not showing - 5.0 Lollipop Android Studio: (AppCompat-v7:r21)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522806/status-bar-color-not-showing-5-0-lollipop-android-studio-appcompat-v7r21)

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36753271/1164529

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The status bar is a system window owned by the operating system. On pre-5.0 Android devices, applications do not have permission to alter its color, so this is not something that the AppCompat library can support for older platform versions. The best AppCompat can do is provide  support for coloring the `ActionBar` and other common UI widgets within the application.

Answer (score 64):

While colouring the status bar is not supported <5.0, on 4.4 you can use a work around to achieve a darker colour:

Make the status bar translucent

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

Then use AppCompat's Toolbar for your appbar, making sure that it fits system windows:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    ...
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
```

Make sure to set your toolbar as your activity's toolbar:

```
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

The toolbar stretches underneath the status bar, and the semi translucency of the status bar makes it appear to be a darker secondary colour.  If that's not the colour you want, this combination allows you to fit a view underneath your status bar sporting the background colour of your choice (though it's still tinted darker by the status bar).

Kind of an edge case workaround due to 4.4 only, but there ya go.

Answer (score 44):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.actionbar));
}
```

Put this code in your Activity's `onCreate` method. This helped me.

Answer (score 13):

As others have also mentioned, this can be readily solved by adding the following to the onCreate() of the Activity:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.primary_dark));
    }
```

However, the important point I want to add here is that in some cases, even the above does not change the status bar color. For example, when using MikePenz library for Navigation Drawer, it implicityly overrides the status bar color, so that you need to manually add the following for it to work:

.withStatusBarColorRes(R.color.status_bar_color)

Answer (score 10):

Status bar coloring is not supported in AppCompat v7:21.0.0.

From the [Android developers blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)

> On older platforms, AppCompat emulates the color theming where possible. At the moment this is limited to coloring the action bar and some widgets.

This means the AppCompat lib will only color status bars on Lollipop and above.

Comment: For that reason, it is obligatory (and it appears in other answers):
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {...

Answer (score 9):

Switch to AppCompatActivity and add a 25 dp paddingTop on the toolbar and turn on

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

Then, the will toolbar go up top the top

Comment: this will work on API 19+ only for above doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

This solution sets the statusbar color of Lollipop, Kitkat and some pre Lollipop devices (Samsung and Sony).
The [SystemBarTintManager](https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint) is managing the Kitkat devices ;)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    hackStatusBarColor(this, R.color.primary_dark);
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static View hackStatusBarColor( final Activity act, final int colorResID ) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        try {

            if (act.getWindow() != null) {

                final ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) act.getWindow().getDecorView();
                if (vg.getParent() == null && applyColoredStatusBar(act, colorResID)) {
                    final View statusBar = new View(act);

                    vg.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            int statusBarHeight = (int) Math.ceil(25 * vg.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
                            statusBar.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, statusBarHeight));
                            statusBar.setBackgroundColor(act.getResources().getColor(colorResID));
                            statusBar.setId(13371337);
                            vg.addView(statusBar, 0);
                        }
                    });
                    return statusBar;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if (act.getWindow() != null) {
        act.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        act.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(act.getResources().getColor(colorResID));
    }
    return null;
}

private static boolean applyColoredStatusBar( Activity act, int colorResID ) {
    final Window window = act.getWindow();
    final int flag;
    if (window != null) {
        View decor = window.getDecorView();
        if (decor != null) {
            flag = resolveTransparentStatusBarFlag(act);

            if (flag != 0) {
                decor.setSystemUiVisibility(flag);
                return true;
            }
            else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                act.findViewById(android.R.id.content).setFitsSystemWindows(false);
                setTranslucentStatus(window, true);
                final SystemBarTintManager tintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(act);
                tintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
                tintManager.setStatusBarTintColor(colorResID);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static int resolveTransparentStatusBarFlag( Context ctx ) {
    String[] libs = ctx.getPackageManager().getSystemSharedLibraryNames();
    String reflect = null;

    if (libs == null)
        return 0;

    final String SAMSUNG = "touchwiz";
    final String SONY = "com.sonyericsson.navigationbar";

    for (String lib : libs) {

        if (lib.equals(SAMSUNG)) {
            reflect = "SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_TRANSPARENT_BACKGROUND";
        }
        else if (lib.startsWith(SONY)) {
            reflect = "SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_TRANSPARENT";
        }
    }

    if (reflect == null)
        return 0;

    try {
        Field field = View.class.getField(reflect);
        if (field.getType() == Integer.TYPE) {
            return field.getInt(null);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return 0;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public static void setTranslucentStatus( Window win, boolean on ) {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();
    final int bits = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS;
    if (on) {
        winParams.flags |= bits;
    }
    else {
        winParams.flags &= ~bits;
    }
    win.setAttributes(winParams);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make *Theme.AppCompa*t style parent

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
     <item name="android:colorPrimary">#005555</item>
     <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#003333</item>
</style>
```

And put `getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext()` in `onCreate()`.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
}
```

Comment: When using AppCompat, don't use the android: prefix with the colors.

Comment: This code has nothing to do with the question. The prefixes are for API 21+ and the code does not do anything.

Comment: how is a getter call supposed to change anything?

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer the question, but with Material Design (API 21+) we can change the color of the status bar by adding this line in the theme declaration in `styles.xml`:

```
<!-- MAIN THEME -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/actionBarCustomization</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/mySpinnerDropDownItemStyle</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/mySpinnerItemStyle</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/myDarkBlue</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Notice the `android:statusBarColor`, where we can define the color, otherwise the default is used.

Comment: I'd suggest it's because "I know this doesn't answer the question, but...", when the question specifically says "I'd like to change the status bar color in pre Android 5...". You submitted this as an answer to the question, when it clearly isn't. Not bashing you, since I realise you were *trying* to be helpful, but hopefully this helps you understand the issue there so you can avoid it in future.

Answer (score 0):

**

### Solution for naughty LOLLIPOP

**

**hello i had rly big problem with having that darker than was my color... so this is solution to avoid that shadow behind status bar from solution with TranslucentStatus...**

so in all of your java activity you need this:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    }
```

and at your styles.xml you need to set background color (this color will be your status bar color):

```
<style name="AppCompat" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/YOUR_STATUS_BAR_COLOR</item>
</style>
```

and at all your layouts you need to add layout which will be your background:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:background="@color/YOUR_BACKGROUND_COLOR"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    />
```

of course if you would like use @color/just name... you need to set that at colors.xml:

```
<color name="YOUR_STATUS_BAR_COLOR">#cf031c</color>
<color name="YOUR_BACKGROUND_COLOR">#383838</color>
```

**here is whole process how we did done that: [Whats the right approach to create or change color of a status bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60188515/whats-the-right-approach-to-create-or-change-color-of-a-status-bar/60197129#60197129)**