# Status Bar Color not showing - 5.0 Lollipop Android Studio: (AppCompat-v7:r21)

Tags: android, android-studio, statusbar, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat

I'm using the `AppCompat-v7:21.0.0` support library for Android 5.0 Lollipop in Android Studio. My problem is that the Status Bar Color that can be changed by setting `colorPrimaryDark` in the `values/styles.xml` file, is showing up as black, in both the xml layout preview and the emulator.

So what's wrong? Am I missing something? Please let me know. Thanks.

**EDIT:** *I'm aware of the fact that changing the status bar color on Pre-Lollipop versions is not possible. My XML Layout Editor Preview and my Emulator are both set to API Level 21 (5.0 Lollipop). But, the status bar still isn't of the color I set it to in `colorPrimaryDark`. I tried doing `statusBarColor` in `styles.xml` but to no avail. It's still black.*

**ALSO:** *I saw one of the answers on a similar question where they advised me to put my `minSdkVersion` to 21. I tried that, but it didn't work. And I want my app to run on devices with API Level 15 and above.*

Comment: I'm having same issue with my 5.0 emulator.  Statusbar does not change color.  Same code on a real device works fine.

Comment: ok cool. Then I will try it on a real device and see. Thanks.

Comment: Same problem here. With Emulator of Android 5.0 it doesn't work. It did work with L-developer preview. Sad.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I currently can't get colorPrimaryDark to color the status bar on 5.0

Comment: @MattWilliams89 is the problem on your device or the emulator? On the emulator and the `layout.xml` on the android studio, the status bar won't show up as colored. On the device however, according to what Patrick said on the above comment, it should work just fine. If it doesn't work on the device either, check out the below answer that I marked and see if that solves your problem... :)

Comment: I'm finding colorPrimaryDark colors the status bar if you use the Galaxy Nexus device in the emulator (or a xhdpi or xxhdp?). Unfortunately it also colors the toolbar as well.

Comment: I have the same issue. On device the status bar color is shown correctly as expected but when I try it on emulator it doesn't work. I tried emulator with 5.0.2 also 5.1. If anyone has found solution please share. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Please read this: For this to take effect, the window must be drawing the system bar backgrounds with

```
android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS
```

but

```
android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS
```

must not be set ([Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setStatusBarColor(int)))

In case of you don't know how to add that flag:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
```

Comment: It's doesn't work, sorry. Thanks for the tip though. Could it be my emulator?

Comment: Test on real device please. It does work on my Nexus 7 but doesn't on emulator. All system bars translucent features don't work on emulator neither.

Comment: Hehe. I don't have a real device with lollipop. But, thank you very much for solving my problem...

Comment: FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS requires API 21 so it won't work on pre-Lollipop devices.

Comment: Hey just a small question here, is there a way to add this flag via xml?

Comment: <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>

Comment: @deviant Thanks! Just a reminder guys, if y'all are gonna be using the `appcompat:v21` library, then it'll be just `<item name="windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true<item>`

Comment: Where should I add the xml item (which styles.xml and under which style definition)? I tried to add it to `values/styles.xml` and `values-v21/styles.xml` under either `<style name="AppTheme"...` or `<style name="AppBaseTheme"...` to no avail

Comment: @ADeveloper No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowDrawSystemBarBackgrounds'.  Running appcompat v22.  Did this change?

Comment: Worked for me using Xamarin equivalent of this.

Comment: Worked for me on real device(as opposed to emulator), using programmatic call in my main activity

Answer (score 36):

This worked for me:

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.some_color));
    }
```

Answer (score 12):

Did you set the target SDK version to 21? I had the same issue when I left the target SDK version to 19. You can leave the min SDK to anything lower.

And of course you need to inherit from the proper theme and make sure your Activity uses it.

Comment: Yes. I had done everything. Turns out the problem is that the emulator and the layout preview are unable to draw the status bar color. The same code is said to work on a real device running lollipop

Comment: It doesn't work in the preview but it does work in the Lollipop emulator. If you open the phone dialer app in the emulator, you should see a blue status bar for example.

Answer (score 7):

Check if you are editing `styles.xml` in `values-v21` folder. If you set SDK version to *21* then it won't look for `styles.xml` in `values` folder(but it should do so).

[image]

Comment: exactly was the problem.

Answer (score 7):

test on my nexus7 5.1.1

set in style.xml v21/v22 is not work

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
```

but

set in actvivity

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark));
}
```

is work for me

Comment: can confirm this. its such i mess... i'm getting sick of this

Comment: can confirm this nexu 5x 6.0.1 and mx5 5.0.1

Comment: Same thing, it drives me crazy, spent couple of days fighting it.

Comment: `getColor` is deprecated. what is the alternative for this? please update your answer

Answer (score 3):

Changing the Status Bar color in pre-Lollipop(5.0) is not possible by setting colorPrimaryDark.    See [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html).

> On older platforms, AppCompat emulates the color theming where possible. At the moment this is limited to coloring the action bar and some widgets.

Comment: I'm aware of that. But the fact that my emulator and my XML Layout Editor Preview are both running API level 21 and it still doesn't work, is where my dilemma arises.

Comment: Hi @patrick, I am new to Android. If Statusbar colors can't be changed with AppCompat library. Then all the google apps are using some other ways to change the status bar colors in their apps? I am using Kitkat and i can see their apps changing the status bar colors. Your view appreciated on this...

Comment: @javaman sure we are both talikinh about the status bar?  The bar at the top of screen with the clock and battery?

Answer (score 1):

In my case `values-v21/styles.xml` contained the following line which overrode the status bar color defined in `values/style.xml` with `colorPrimaryDark`:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Removing this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In `v22-appcompat` they (Android) have now added rendering of the status bar color in the android studio preview!

About time... Anyways, make sure your `appcompat` library is updated to the latest version, which is v22.0.+.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the culprit was `jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu` library.
I replaced the library with `Android navigation drawer` and now it displays status bar color correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on an old app and trying to convert it to material style. The code and everything was fine however the only mistake I had that was hindering the status bar tinting on >= Lollipop devices was **"TargetSDKVersion"** in **build.gradle**. It was set to less then 21. I changed it to 21 and statusbar tinting started working.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
Removed the status bar color from styles. 
Add flag and then put the color you want like so

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color));
}
```