# How to change the color of notification bar using AppCompat class in android studio?

Tags: android, android-statusbar

I want to change the color of status bar when api level is 21 and higher. It's not working for me. I'm also using `supportActionBar`. I'm using the codes below:

**values/styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    !-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
     <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text</item>
     <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondary_text</item>

  </style>

  <!-- Application theme. -->
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.ToolBar" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.NavMenu" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/gray</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.RightMenu" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

In manifest file I set `android:theme="@style/MyTheme"`

**values-v21/styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

This is my colors file:

```
<resources>
  <color name="primary">#3F51B5</color>
  <color name="primary_dark">#303F9F</color>
  <color name="primary_light">#C5CAE9</color>
  <color name="accent">#FFC107</color>
  <color name="primary_text">#212121</color>
  <color name="secondary_text">#727272</color>
  <color name="icons">#FFFFFF</color>
  <color name="divider">#B6B6B6</color>
</resources>
```

What's wrong with my styles and why isn't it changing status bar color??

Comment: Use <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/xxx</item> in your values-v21 file

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm using Xamarin adding these lines in the base activity solved the problem:

```
Window window = this.Window;
window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);
```

For Java [refer to this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522806/status-bar-color-not-showing-5-0-lollipop-android-studio-appcompat-v7r21).

Answer (score 1):

Status bar color can be set by colorPrimaryDark,

In your values-v21/styles.xml add

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimayDark</item>
</style></resources>
```

and YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity

Comment: First there are errors in your xml, second it doesn't work.

Comment: try removing statusBarColor from v21

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
<style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
<item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
```

Comment: I can't use `DarkActionBar` as I'm using a support action bar.

Comment: Add this to your styles.xml `<item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
<item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>`

Comment: Read this article https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/, maybe you'll find something useful.

Comment: Nothing new over there.

Answer (score 0):

Status bar color is drawn from the `colorPrimaryDark` color value for your App Style. Just change it to whatever color you want the actionbar to be, it'll get changed.

**styles.sml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <!--This is your default actionbar color-->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!--change this to whatever you need-->
    <color name="colorPrimary">#03A9F4</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#0277BD</color
</resources>
```

Comment: I posted my colors file, is there something wrong with mine??

Comment: Well I use the same set of codes and works well for me. I'll try out your style code and check.

Comment: Solved it. Please check my answer. Apparently it's a known issue with Appcompat v7 from support library.

Comment: Where have you posted answer?