# No color is shown on my Material Design ActionBar or StatusBar in Lollipop devices, but is shown in ActionBar of Pre-Lollipop devices. Why?

Tags: android, material-design

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hrlGVU8z7zc&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6CtAMbJz1XD8ELUs1KXaTD&index=2) to use colors in (my ActionBar and StatusBar) in Android Material design. I did follow the tutorial but no color is reflected, and the same dark ActionBar and StatusBar are shown when I run the app in my `API22` emulator, while color is shown in the ActionBar of Pre-lollipop devices The question is why and how can I fix this?

`minimumSdkVersion` is `8` and `targetSdkVersion` is `22`. It compiles with `5.1.1 API 22`. The emulator to test for Lollipop devices is Nexus One but customised to run `API 22`, whereas the emulator to test for Pre-lollipop devices is running `API 08`

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryColorDark)); 
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**res/values/color.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="primaryColor">#FF5722</color>
    <color name="primaryColorDark">#E64A19</color>
    <color name="accentColor">#9C27B0</color>
</resources>
```

**res/values/styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" ></style>


    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

The same (as ^) code is there in `res/values-v11/styles.xml` and `res/values-14/styles.xml`.

**res/values-v21/styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

The same (as ^) code is there in `res/values-v22/styles.xml`.

---

EDIT The left one is running API 22, and the right one is running API 08.

[image]

Comment: Can you post more information? Snippets of code? Anything we can look at to determine what goes wrong?

Comment: What did you try so far? Show some code.

Comment: @Rob Sorry I had mistakenly posted the question earlier. Just edited it to show more information.

Comment: @ThomasR. Sorry I had mistakenly posted the question earlier. Just edited it to show more information.

Comment: where is AppTheme.Base style??

Comment: @Solace you are folowing slidenerd tutorial check this may be helpful for you https://github.com/slidenerd/materialtest and your  issue in style check it

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar I am so sorry (I was a bit freaked out after posting the question too soon) I pasted the wrong file in `values/styles.xml`. Just edited and corrected in the question.

Comment: @AmanJham I never understand how to use that one app to test everything. It has tons of other features, and doesn't have a simple minimalistic app to test my app against, for the particular feature that I have used/tested in my app. =s

Comment: Is `AppTheme` set to `android:theme` in your manifest?

Comment: @PPartisan Yep `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

Comment: maybe you can try my answer about statusbar ,http://stackoverflow.com/a/30023811/998953

Comment: @user998953 It didn't help me =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in **MainActivity.java**
change

`public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {`

to

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

in **res/values/styles.xml**

replace everything with this

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#e23c7f</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#dae22b</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#5863e3</item>
</style>
```

If none of the above works, add the following snippet inside the onCreate() method

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources() 
.getColor(R.color.primaryColorDark)));
```

Finally you will get something like this:

[image]

Comment: of course. Did you set the theme in the manifest?
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

Comment: There is no other way this happening. Does the Android studio preview the right color or the wrong?

Comment: I just added a screenshot to the question. It is showing the color in the ActionBar in a Pre-Lollipop device, but not in a Lollipop device :s

Comment: did you also changed the res/values-v21/styles.xml content with the style in my answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85106/discussion-between-solace-and-giorgos-oikonomou).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using api 22; in styles 21.xml change `android:colorPrimary` to `colorPrimary` just like in styles.xml for older devices, and all rest color values in styles from v21.xml