# Changing the Status bar color on Android kitkat

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat

Hey i am trying to change the color of the status bar to be the same as the action bar color (maybe transparent). On Android Lolipop it is not a problem but on Kitkat [it looks like on this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdwIO.png)

I tried many others solution but it still not fix it.

here is the v19 xml style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>

</style>
```

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496411/android-material-status-bar-color-wont-change

Comment: @SteveM I tried but it still not working

Comment: what exactly is not working? On KitKat you should be able to make the status bar translucent and put a color beneath it as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27516736/919219

Answer (score -3):

This is not possible in Android 4.4 API level 19.
You can do it from Android 5.0 API level 21 and forward.

Comment: translucent status was introduced in API 19, so it's possible to make it translucent and put a color beneath it

Comment: @Zielony this is work-around, and not an elegant solution.