# How to change the colour of the statusbar in android?

Tags: android, styles, android-manifest, statusbar

This is my style

```
 <style name="NoActionbar" parent="android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">

    <item name="android:statusBarColor">#1c465d</item>

</style

>
```

I want to change the splash screen, by remove the actionbar
but i realise the default status bar colour is black, I am not able to change the colour of statusbar to green

why is this show?

How can I do it?

Comment: getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hdr_bar));

Comment: Refer to this link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496411/android-material-status-bar-color-wont-change). Good luck & hope this helps.

Comment: Why don't you set your Splash Screen to a FullScreen Activity?

Comment: also you can set using code  http://stackoverflow.com/a/30023811/3790150

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated above, set the colorPrimaryDark attribute in your style to whatever you like.

```
<resources>
  <!-- inherit from the material theme -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <!-- Main theme colors -->
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html

To do it correctly you should declare your color value in the color.xml, then reference it from the style.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the status bar color by defining the `colorPrimaryDark` item:

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1c465d</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

go to ~values/color.xml and replace `colorPrimaryDark`

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1c465d</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you can set status bar color programatically

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);         getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_dark));
}
```