# Android status bar color not changing

Tags: android, statusbar

[image]I have an Activity and a Fragment in my project.In the Activity I set the layout take the entire screen and in fragment I try to change the status bar color programmatically. The status bar is shown over the layout but the color is not changed.

Activity:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        }
```

Fragment:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
            getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                Log.e("statusbarcolor","changing..");
                getActivity().getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.statusBarColor));
            }
        }
```

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android and http://stackoverflow.com/a/26623245/2784663

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496411/android-material-status-bar-color-wont-change

Comment: Make sure testing on =>21

Comment: Why don't you just use the xml way to do it?

Comment: @YLS I changed it but it did not work

Comment: I tried using  getActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);           getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
But it did not change

Answer (score 4):

I guess , Problem is your   **Build.VERSION.SDK_INT** section .

In my case **(Activity)**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    {
        Window window = activity.getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#54d66a");
    }
```

Comment: @jobin add `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` before `setContentView(R.layout.`

Answer (score 0):

Just try doing:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```

Just tested this with ActionBarActivity and it works alright.

Note: Setting the FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS flag programmatically is not necessary if your values-v21 styles file has it set already, via:

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
```

Create a method in your activity

```
public void updateStatusBarColor(String color){// Color must be in hexadecimal fromat
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor(color));
    }
}
```

Call this method from your fragment

```
((ActivityName)getActivity()).updateStatusBarColor("#000000")
```

In given below using my application :

```
..................
 switch (position) {
        case 0 :
            fragment = new SampleOneFragment();
            color = R.color.ColorPrimaryDark;
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new SampleOneFragment();
            color = R.color.AlertRed_dark;
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new SampleOneFragment();
            color = R.color.ProgressBarPurple_dark;
            break;
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, color));
    }  
    replaceFragment(fragment);
}
```

Comment: Why use **Deprecated** `ActionBarActivity`

Comment: android version 22.1.0, the class ActionBarActivity is deprecated. You should use to AppCompatActivity.

Comment: @Manikandan K.I tried your code,it still has not changed

Comment: I now used  getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);   getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);            getActivity().getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#8f1745"));

Comment: WhenI used the above code the status bar is shown,but the color has not changed

Comment: Please replace getActivity().getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor‌​("#8f1745")); to getActivity().  getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.LogsPBYellow_dark));

Comment: I have included the screenshot in my question

Comment: Are you using ToolBar?

Answer (score 0):

I did it finally.I simply used the below code in my fragment:

```
getActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.FLAG_FULL_SCREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

User this code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

            Window window = getWindow();
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_statusbar_color));
        }
```