# Whats the right approach to create or change color of a status bar?

Tags: java, android, notifications, statusbar

I have a quiet big problem with changing the color of my status bar.
The device on which I working on is telling me android 5.1 but staff like `windowTranslucentStatus` or `android:colorPrimaryDark` or `android:statusBarColor` just does not work at all (translucent have like 20% dark transparence) and anything else does not work.

so it seems like it is something under android 5.0.

So I tried some applications - one did work because they made their own status bar in front of old ones. but the first thing I do not won't use the different app and second thing this app can not do animation notification which I using in my project

so I made a button with my color in front of my status bar but now I need to add there all icons. (i need there only wifi, bluetooth, battery, time.) that is it but I found that quite hard.

so now I am little bit stuck does anyone know hack how to change that color or how to somehow replicate notification icons? I do not need to slide notification bar I just need that to be seen.

Comment: thanks i am from czech and do not know rly well english @AndroidAnton

Comment: thanks @saeed foroughi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So last thing yes it does works this is ony one code whitch does not leave behind status bar shadow... do not know why but yes this was solution for me... i made in styles my background red... and on all screens (layouts) i add behind everything layout from edge to edge... so my background is now this layout... and real background is only for status bar...

solution like TranslucentStatus and little layout with my color did left shadow behind status bar so i never could get exactly that color which i needed... and solutions like statusbarcolor or primarydarkcolor programaticly or at styles never worked... so if you have this problem you can do this ugly solution... but it definitly work...

big thanks to @Muhammad Muzammil Sharif without him i will never get to this point... (3 people at my company tryed to do that whole week)

this is final wersion... now i would like to hide some of thoes system notifications... but i do not thing that is possible... thanks again to everyone
[image]

[image]

[image]

so in all of your java activity you need this:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    }
```

and at your styles.xml you need to set background color (this color will be your status bar color):

```
<style name="AppCompat" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/YOUR_STATUS_BAR_COLOR</item>
</style>
```

and at all your layouts you need to add layout which will be your background:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:background="@color/YOUR_BACKGROUND_COLOR"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    />
```

of course if you would like use @color/just name... you need to set that at colors.xml:

```
<color name="YOUR_STATUS_BAR_COLOR">#cf031c</color>
<color name="YOUR_BACKGROUND_COLOR">#383838</color>
```

Comment: this is solution !

Answer (score 1):

you can set it in `androidMenifest.xml` in activity or app theme e.g.

```
<activity
     android:theme="@style/activityTheme"
     android:name=".MyActivity"
     android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

in `style.xml`

```
<style name="activityTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

`colorPrimaryDark` is status bar color for the activity

if you wanted to change it pro-grammatically you can use bellow code

for Activity

```
Kotlin
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
     window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.YOUR_COLOR)
}

Java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
     getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.COLOR));
}
```

for Fragment

```
Kotlin
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
     activity.window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.YOUR_COLOR)
}

Java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
     getActivity().getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.COLOR));
}
```

Comment: public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            DeleniUctuActivity.Window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color_red_real);
        }
so i tried this but it can not resolved symbol window

Comment: from style it always work could you give some code that you are trying in style and in your manifest file

Comment: try `getWindow()`

Comment: above code is in kotlin language let me edit it into java

Comment: mabie wait... i testing programatic way

Comment: are you getting some error or color is not changing

Comment: only one thing which change my status bar is android:windowTranslucentStatus nothing else does not react.    no errors now

Comment: few days earlier i even tryed to make new app just for status bar color... it does not changed too... i rly thing that device is lier

Comment: what is device sdk version you are testing on

Comment: if you are using `FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS` then you need to call `getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);` and `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);` before changing color

Comment: i send picture to my answere... and yep i trying now that flag translucent status = nothing changed  
 
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color_red_real));
        }

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Muhammad Muzammil Sharif

Comment: thanks for all help.. with that FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS i had done it...

Answer (score 0):

**manifest**

```
<application android:name="com.smartpos.pocket.app.PocketApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:allowBackup="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="com.smartpos.pocket.activity.impl.StartUpActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

**styles (i have project at api 17)**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppCompat">
</style>
```

**styles v21**

```
<style name="AppCompat" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_red_real</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_red_real</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_red_real</item>
</style>
```

status bar does not change anything i thing that device is a laier and there is not android 5.1 or i do not know...

[image]

Comment: i am sory @Muhammad Muzammil Sharif i did not know what is SDK version you mean on my computer there is check Android 10 and Android 8

Answer (score 0):

hmmm it can be changed... mabie becouse Theme.AppCompat is dark and Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar is light

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_red_real</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_red_real</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_red_real</item>
</style>[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_red_real</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_red_real</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_red_real</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: i know why now... that transluence does work... and by this way it does not make that shadow... ou yeah