# Change status bar color with AppCompat ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar

In one of my Activities, I changed the Toolbar color using `Palette`.  But on 5.0 devices using `ActionBarActivity` the `status bar` color is the color of my `colorPrimaryDark` in my activity theme so I have 2 very different colors and it does not look good.

I realize that in 5.0 you can use `Window.setStatusBarColor()` but `ActionBarActivity` does not have this.

so my question is in 5.0 how can I change the status bar color with `ActionBarActivity`?

Comment: Have you tried to use SystemBarTint lib ?https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the status bar color in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android)

Answer (score 475, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the problem.

I you want to change the status bar color programmatically (and provided the device has Android 5.0) then you **can** use [`Window.setStatusBarColor()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setStatusBarColor%28int%29). It shouldn't make a difference whether the activity is derived from `Activity` or `ActionBarActivity`.

Just try doing:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```

Just tested this with `ActionBarActivity` and it works alright.

---

Note: Setting the `FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS` flag programmatically is not necessary if your `values-v21` styles file has it set already, via:

```
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
```

Comment: ah ok I wasnt using `getWindow()`

Comment: this would crash when code LOLLIPOP is not found in old androids. its best to use >=21

Comment: @code578841441 Actually, that should not happen. Constants are inlined when compiling.

Comment: @code578841441: That is because you're compiling with an older SDK. You should always strive for *compiling* with the latest Android SDK, even if you have older API version constraints (i.e. `minSdkVersion` and/or `targetSdkVersion` attributes on the `<uses-sdk ...>` element).

Comment: I also had to call getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS); to make it work

Comment: How do you do that for the whole app and not just the activity?

Comment: @Spacemonkey By setting `android:statusBarColor` in your theme.

Comment: @matiash I meant programmatically

Comment: @Spacemonkey Oh... there is no way that I know of. You need to call `setStatusBarColor()` in every activity's `onCreate()` (or in a base class for all activities, of course).

Comment: As a note the color int should be retrieved as `getColor(res_id)` , if the color is taken from your colors xml

Comment: the getWindow() does not exist in the page context. How are you using?

Comment: I want change to white, but icons stay white also, so they desapear

Comment: this will change color but not in my desire color what is the issue?

Answer (score 68):

There are various ways of changing the status bar color.

1. Using the styles.xml. You can use the android:statusBarColor attribute to do this the easy but static way.

Note: You can also use this attribute with the Material theme.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

2. You can get it done dynamically using the setStatusBarColor(int) method in the Window class. But remember that this method is only available for API 21 or higher. So be sure to check that, or your app will surely crash in lower devices.

Here is a working example of this method.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryDark));
}
```

where primaryDark is the 700 tint of the primary color I am using in my app. You can define this color in the colors.xml file.

Comment: it looks like window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS); is not needed - but this one worked for me

Comment: Any ideas why the programmatic version would work but the style version doesn't?

Comment: In my case the activity's style had the flah translucent_status set, so without the window.clearFlags command it didn't work. So thank you for this!

Comment: Oh wow! This should be accepted answer, add `clearFlags` fix my issue

Answer (score 9):

I don't think the status bar color has been implemented in AppCompat yet. These are the attributes which are available:

```
    <!-- ============= -->
    <!-- Color palette -->
    <!-- ============= -->

    <!-- The primary branding color for the app. By default, this is the color applied to the
         action bar background. -->
    <attr name="colorPrimary" format="color" />

    <!-- Dark variant of the primary branding color. By default, this is the color applied to
         the status bar (via statusBarColor) and navigation bar (via navigationBarColor). -->
    <attr name="colorPrimaryDark" format="color" />

    <!-- Bright complement to the primary branding color. By default, this is the color applied
         to framework controls (via colorControlActivated). -->
    <attr name="colorAccent" format="color" />

    <!-- The color applied to framework controls in their normal state. -->
    <attr name="colorControlNormal" format="color" />

    <!-- The color applied to framework controls in their activated (ex. checked) state. -->
    <attr name="colorControlActivated" format="color" />

    <!-- The color applied to framework control highlights (ex. ripples, list selectors). -->
    <attr name="colorControlHighlight" format="color" />

    <!-- The color applied to framework buttons in their normal state. -->
    <attr name="colorButtonNormal" format="color" />

    <!-- The color applied to framework switch thumbs in their normal state. -->
    <attr name="colorSwitchThumbNormal" format="color" />
```

(From **\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values\attrs.xml**)

Comment: It's possible that it will never be implemented in AppCompat if the older OS versions do not provide any ability to modify the status bar.

Comment: <attr name="colorPrimaryDark" format="color" />
<!-- Dark variant of the primary branding color. By default, this is the color applied to the status bar (via statusBarColor) and navigation bar (via navigationBarColor). -->

Answer (score 8):

Just paste this function in your Utils class where you keep your all other common functions.

```
fun Activity.changeStatusBarColor(color: Int, isLight: Boolean) {
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
    window.statusBarColor = color

    WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = isLight
}
```

and use it from anywhere like this:

```
changeStatusBarColor(
        ContextCompat.getColor(
            context,
            R.color.black
        ), false
    )
```

Note that here I also have managed the dark and light status bar colors separately to manage out icon and text colors of status bar.

Comment: On API 21, then the status is white, the text and icon are white too.

Answer (score 3):

[Kotlin version] I created this extension that also checks if the desired color has enough contrast to hide the System UI, like Battery Status Icon, Clock, etc, so we set the System UI white or black according to this.

```
fun Activity.coloredStatusBarMode(@ColorInt color: Int = Color.WHITE, lightSystemUI: Boolean? = null) {
    var flags: Int = window.decorView.systemUiVisibility // get current flags
    var systemLightUIFlag = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
    var setSystemUILight = lightSystemUI

    if (setSystemUILight == null) {
        // Automatically check if the desired status bar is dark or light
        setSystemUILight = ColorUtils.calculateLuminance(color) < 0.5
    }

    flags = if (setSystemUILight) {
        // Set System UI Light (Battery Status Icon, Clock, etc)
        removeFlag(flags, systemLightUIFlag)
    } else {
        // Set System UI Dark (Battery Status Icon, Clock, etc)
        addFlag(flags, systemLightUIFlag)
    }

    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = flags
    window.statusBarColor = color
}

private fun containsFlag(flags: Int, flagToCheck: Int) = (flags and flagToCheck) != 0

private fun addFlag(flags: Int, flagToAdd: Int): Int {
    return if (!containsFlag(flags, flagToAdd)) {
        flags or flagToAdd
    } else {
        flags
    }
}

private fun removeFlag(flags: Int, flagToRemove: Int): Int {
    return if (containsFlag(flags, flagToRemove)) {
        flags and flagToRemove.inv()
    } else {
        flags
    }
}
```

Comment: This works like charm, but the only problem is the usage of deprecated methods!

Answer (score 2):

Try this,
I used this and it works very good with v21.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for above answers, with the help of those, after certain R&D for xamarin.android MVVMCross application, below worked

Flag specified for activity in method OnCreate

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        this.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);
    }
```

For  each MvxActivity, Theme is mentioned as below

```
 [Activity(
    LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop,
    ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait,
    Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash",
    Name = "MyView"
    )]
```

My SplashStyle.xml looks like as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources> 
    <style name="Theme.Splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
          <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/app_red</item>
          <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/app_red</item>
    </style>
 </resources>
```

And I have V7 appcompact referred.

Answer (score 0):

Applying

```
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
```

in `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` didn't worked for me. What did the trick is , giving `colorPrimaryDark` as usual along with  `android:colorPrimary` in styles.xml

```
<item name="android:colorAccent">@color/color_primary</item>
<item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
<item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
```

and in setting

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
                {
                    Window window = this.Window;
                    Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);
                }
```

didn't had to set statusbar color in code .

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented if you're using Kotlin in Android:

```
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
window.statusBarColor = Color.WHITE
```

Answer (score 0):

add this `kotlin` code in `OnCreate()` of `Activity` or `Fragment` :

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            val window: Window = requireActivity().window
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
            window.statusBarColor = resources.getColor(R.color.very_light_pink)
        }
```