# Change statusbar color on Fragment change [Android Lollipop]

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm wondering how to change the StatusBar color dependent on the current active Fragment (on 5.0 Lollipop). Currently, I change the ActionBar color dependent on the Fragment I am in, but now I want the StatusBar color to change as well - in order to look nice on Lollipop devices.

I've tried using setStyle to programmatically change the theme depending on the fragment, but it doesn't seem to be changing the status bar color.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the code that you've tried?

Comment: It's a little messy, but essentially I have a FragmentData object which stores the style (amongst other things) I want for each fragment. Whenever the fragment changes I setStyle to the mStyle field I have in that object. Just a side note: This is working to change the actionbar color, it's just that the statusbar color doesn't seem to be set.

Comment: Yeah of course. This isn't just for me - it's for anybody reading the question.

Comment: Right, heres a chunk of the code Im using right now:

        `if (fragmentData != null) {
            updateActionBarForFragment(fragmentData);
            mStyle = fragmentData.getStyle();
        } 

        setTheme(mStyle);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change status bar color with AppCompat ActionBarActivity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26702000/change-status-bar-color-with-appcompat-actionbaractivity)

Answer (score 20):

Have you tried to change the color of the status bar using `Window.setStatusBarColor`? For example, you can do the following to change the status bar color to red programmatically.

```
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.RED);
```

The documentation of `setStatusBarColor` can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setStatusBarColor(int)). You can also read the documentation on how to [Customize the Status Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#StatusBar).

**Note:** This method only works at Lollipop or above.

If you are seeing an unexpected color, make sure the integer value you are passing is a *color integer* and not a resource ID.

```
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.custom_color)); // RIGHT
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(R.color.custom_color); // WRONG
```

Comment: So, `getWindow().setStatusBarColor(...)` works to change the status bar color, but its not setting the right color. So for example, when I set the status bar color to orange, it comes out as purple. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: is there a way to do the same in android 4.4 ?

Comment: @AminKeshavarzian You have to use app compact, and do `<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/BackgroundColor</item>' in your style or theme xml to support android 4.4 devices.

Comment: Changing status bar's color programmatically is just possible in API 21 ? I want to change the color programmatically in API less than 21 , Is it possible ?