# How to remove space from Tool bar in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I am working on an android app, in which I need to make transparent the `Status bar` and `Toolbar`.

How to remove the left and right space coming in `Toolbar`, highlighted in red line ?

I am doing this as follows :

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/action_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/main_activity_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**And action_bar_main.xml is :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="de.slowpoke.android.news.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/newsAppToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#51000000"
            android:clickable="false" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Style used is as follows :**

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">#51000000</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: please post the full layout

Answer (score 0):

**That's because of :**

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">#51000000</item>
```

Which you already have :

```
android:background="#51000000"
```

As the `background` for your `Toolbar`.

You may also want to use this:

```
android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
```

Instead of:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

And one thing more, That `Toolbar` shouldn't be there, you should use that with :

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

For `StatusBar` color.

Comment: Then where should I place the Toolbar

Comment: `Toolbar`'s position is good, but seems like that `statusBarColor` screwed up the layout, just use `colorPrimaryDark`

Comment: But I want to make Status bar and Tool bar of same color, i.e. 50% Transparent.I guess, colorPrimaryDark will not be useful for 50% transparency.

Comment: Since that will pass the rules, you can use `<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>` these codes will set whatever colors you want to toolbar and statusbar see: http://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html

Comment: Is it possible to use Tool bar outside AppBarLayout. As I did this, so the space is removed from left and right in the Tool bar, what I actually want but the data is not getting populated.

Comment: You can use that with a Root tag like `RelativeLayout`, but it's not recommended, you can achieve a lot of effects for materialdesgin with CoordinatorLayout and AppbarLayout.and this question already has answers i guess: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26702000/change-status-bar-color-with-appcompat-actionbaractivity