# Changing The Color Of Android Top Bar

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to change the color of top/notification bar on Xamarin Forms Portable Class Library. I have tried using the following:

```
 MainPage.SetValue(NavigationPage.BarTextColorProperty, Color.FromHex(#424242);
```

Source: [Xamarin.Forms - Change StatusBar Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37993741/xamarin-forms-change-statusbar-color)

I have also tried using

```
    public App()
{
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page1())
    {
        BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#424242"),
        BarTextColor = Color.White,
    };
}
```

Source: https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2016/02/12/setting-the-navigationbar-colors-in-xamarin-forms/

In first instance/code the app launches, however gets stuck at loading screen. Am also new to using Xamarin, so unsure where to find error logs for this as none were displayed in the console.

In the second instance/code the app colors the area on top of the application/under the notification bar but not the notification bar itself.

Hope someone can guide me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked my answer? Any problem?

Comment: Hey, yeah I tried it and launched on Nexus emulator, the system bar still comes up in default (blue color). I rebuilt/cleaned the solution, not sure what I am doing wrong. Appreciate the help btw :)

Comment: Which android version is your emulator's OS?

Comment: Android 5.0 I think

Comment: Then my solution should work, as you can see from [setStatusBarColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setStatusBarColor%28int%29), it is supported from API level 21. And you can check the [test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCb4Z.png) of my code. You can also check [this similar thread on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26702000/change-status-bar-color-with-appcompat-actionbaractivity).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first method is trying to change the text color(so to say "foreground color") of notification bar and your second method is trying to change the background color of navigation bar, and since you said:

> In the second instance/code the app colors the area on top of the application/under the notification bar but not the notification bar itself.

I guess that you want to change the background color of system's status bar, not the one of application's navigation bar. Then you can only change it in your android project, not in PCL.

For example, open your `MainActivity` of android project and modify the `OnCreate` method like this:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
    LoadApplication(new App());

    Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);
    Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);
    Window.SetStatusBarColor(Color.LightPink);
}
```