# How to set a dark overlay on a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker, statusbar, bottomnavigationview

I've used a "Black ImageView" (with alpha = 0.7) to create a dark overlay under my "Pop-Up Message" but it not affect on "Status Bar" & "Bottom Navigation Bar"! (Please see the image)

***Image:*** [image]

**How can I set a dark overlay on whole of the fragment?**

Comment: same way as on any other view - add another layout to the root view of your fragment, and add a view with a dark half-transparent background on top of your fragment's view.

Comment: You can't change status bar color by adding `ImageView` ... for changing status bar color ....use programmatical methods . See this question for reference https://stackoverflow.com/q/26702000/9636037

Comment: @Abhi Thanks! It works for status bar, but what about "BottomNavigationView"?

Comment: Post your layout code