# ANDROID : App Bar or Status Bar is not the same with main activity

Tags: android

This is bothering me because I know it is a simple issue but I can't get to fix it.

so I want my app bar or status bar to have same style.

here is my main activity:

[image]

and this is my 2nd activity which have a different app bar or status bar

[image]

and this is the xml code of my 2nd activity which contains an appbar layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

this is the style.xml

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

and this is the manifest

```
<application
    android:name=".app.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ApplicationActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_application"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".activity.ProfileActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activity.ResetPasswordActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activity.SignupActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activity.LoginActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.AboutUsActivity"
        android:label="@string/activity_title_about_us" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.PrivacyPolicyActivity"
        android:label="@string/activity_title_privacy_policy" />
</application>
```

and this is the activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Comment: Can you share the manifest and styles.xml?

Comment: manifest and styles added

Comment: which of these activities is the second activity you mention?

Comment: the one that have a title Activity

Comment: Application rather

Comment: can you also share the xml for the first screen? It would help if we could compare the two layouts

Comment: @chinnc main activity xml added

Comment: Out of curiosity what happens when you change 
`<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />`
to 
`<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar" />` in the style.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this to your NoActionBar style

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
   <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
   <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
   <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
   <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
   <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

and check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26702000/change-status-bar-color-with-appcompat-actionbaractivity)