# How to change statusbar text color to dark on android 4.4

Tags: android

Almost 2 weeks ago, I was searching How to change the text color of the statusbar to dark color on android 4.4

The default text color is white, like this

Because I have not enough votes, So I can not post pictures. 
[see detail with pictures at here](http://www.cnblogs.com/iihe602/p/4217266.html)

I'd like to change the topmost text color to dark, How can I do?

At the meaning time, I find a app had do,

[download jumei app](http://hd.jumei.com/act/9-478-1477-download_app.html?from=Home_top_nav_fresh_mobile_tab_new&site=bj)

I'm so sorry for My poor English, thank you!

Comment: The links in your question did not work. Please edit.

Comment: I change the link, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to change the color of the status bar in android. The only thing you can set in your app is the status bar's background color (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22192291/3593126)).

Maybe you can post some more information about your problem <s>(your links don't work)</s>.

Comment: Can you please give the name or a link to the app?

Comment: The link is  http://hd.jumei.com/act/9-478-1477-download_app.html?from=Home_top_nav_fresh_mobile_tab_new&site=bj

Comment: Hm I'm sorry, the app doesn't change the text color in my statusbar

Comment: I finally find jumei app is only show black text on my XiaoMi 4 Phone, on the other phone, it shows white text and black background.

Answer (score 11):

You can not set the status bar text color by specifying any color explicitly

But you can try below alternative which is Added in API 23,

You can use "android:windowLightStatusBar" attribute in two ways

- "android:windowLightStatusBar" = true, status bar text color will
  be compatible (grey) when status bar color is light
- "android:windowLightStatusBar" = false, status bar text color will
  be compatible (white) when status bar color is dark

> ```
> <style name="statusBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light">
>     <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/status_bar_color</item>
>     <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
> </style>
> ```

You can check above api in below link -
    https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowLightStatusBar