# Android AppBar Text Color Aren't Changing

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout, android-statusbar

I can't change the color of android windows title bar text color. I don't know what is the name to this. So I'm providing you a screenshot to understand. please see the blow image:
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixNDm.png)

I searched for this question, but i didn't get any tutorials or answer from another forum. my post activity is showing the text color white. but home activity and another activity showing the text color Black.

I'm using toolbar layout. below provided toolbar xml code:

toolbar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:weightSum="1"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            android:background="@color/red"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <net.gurujibd.jamunanews.view.PhenomenaTextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="@color/title_color"
                    android:textSize="21sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imgBtnSearch"
                    android:layout_width="22dp"
                    android:layout_height="22dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_search" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/notificationView"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imgBtnSearch"
                    android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:clickable="true">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/notiIcon"
                        android:layout_width="22dp"
                        android:layout_height="22dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_notification" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/notificationCount"
                        android:layout_width="16dp"
                        android:layout_height="16dp"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/notiIcon"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/badge_circle"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="0dp"
                        android:text="5"
                        android:textColor="#FFF"
                        android:textSize="9sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </RelativeLayout>


            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.7dp"
            android:background="@color/toolbar_boarder" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:weightSum="1"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.7dp"
        android:background="@color/toolbar_boarder" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

hope i will get solution for this question.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is called **status bar**.

**For api above 21:**

In `style.xml`

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/status_bar_color</item>
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
```

here

1.(added in api 21)`android:statusBarColor` is background color of status bar and

2.(added in api 23)`android:windowLightStatusBar` value `false` makes status bar text color white and gray is `true`.

**For all api level, only changing status bar background color**

It takes it's color from from style.xml

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
```

Change primary_dark from colors.xml to change status bar color

```
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#bd3874ff</color>
```

Comment: are you seen my screenshot image? please see the screenshot and ans. your current ans isn't working.

Comment: i want to make the status bar text color white for all api level. how can i do that? i was tried with changing the colorPrimaryDark in my style. it's not working. please let me know how to do that?

Comment: sadly there is no option to change statusbar text color for api below 23. Check this question and answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888102/how-to-change-statusbar-text-color-to-dark-on-android-4-4

Comment: what is the default color of statusbar text? it's my first app with custom style. basically it's showing status bar color black. i just want to convert it in white color.

Comment: thanks... i got it. done this with adding this line on v23\styles.xml "<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>"