# How to change font colour black in Wifi, clock and battery icons of statusbar in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fonts, android-statusbar

Currently font colour of Wifi, clock and battery in statusbar(top) of android phone is white. We have a requirement to change its colour to black. It is a worklight project. Using API 19. Any idea?

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far. Changing the color of the status bar is probably a duplicate question

Comment: I think this will display based on the themes...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464234/android-lollipop-set-status-bar-text-color/33509124#33509124 Hope this helps..

Comment: Where to add these lines. I do not find any styles.xml file in my workspace. There is AndroidManifest.xml and config.xml

    <style name="statusBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light">
            <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/status_bar_color</item>
            <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
    </style>

Answer (score 1):

It is possible only from API 23 and above use following style in you app

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

You can also change the flag at runtime by setting it to any View:

```
    View yourView = findViewById(R.id.your_view);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
         if (yourView != null) { 
               yourView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
         }
    }
```

Comment: I am using API 19. I do not find styles.xml to add this line.

Comment: The above mentioned solution will only work from API level 23 and above..
You can find styles.xml or create one in res->values->styles.xml