# Change status bar font color on Android

Tags: android, android-statusbar

Is there any way to change statusBar font and icons color on Android ? (Not talking about the background color)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the status bar color in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android)

Comment: Apparently, it isn't I have seen this post, but it's about changing status bar background color, not icons and font color. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: the top answer covers font color, i'm not sure you can change other peoples icons though.

Comment: Status bar is the Android's bar where notifications are showed up. What icons would you like to change? Do you mean Toolbar or Action Bar?

Comment: Hey, I probably mixted up sorry, I mean the bar which contains Wifi, clock and battery icons. Generally located at the top of screen application. Is my issue solvable ?

Comment: This is a duplicate questions.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android