# Status bar android kitkat color?

Tags: android

Is there is some way to change the status bar color in android versions below lollipop, such as kitkat? If so, then how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

See [How to change the status bar color in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android). Android lollipop introduced the material design allowing the notification color changing you desire.

Comment: There are comments in the link above taking about KitKat. I'm not familiar with this but it looks like api 19+ you can make the color adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do using the library [SystemBarTint](https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint). [System Bar Tint Sample](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.readystatesoftware.systembartint.sample) is a sample app which implements the library.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for myself, we need to create styles value for res/values-v19/styles.xml like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:clipToPadding">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

if we use `CoordinatorLayout` as root view we got translucent status bar and navigation bottom bar fade with `android:windowBackground` color, if we use general layout like `Linear` or `Relative` layout we got completely transparent status and navigation bar like we use `DrawerLayout` it will give same result. adding `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in root layout will give content keep inside the application container to avoid collapse or overlapping with status bar or navigation bar.