# Status bar color, Android

Tags: android, colors, statusbar

Here is the problem, I am using toolbar and I am making it's background color white (or grey, doesn't make difference).

Toolbar code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:theme="@style/AppTheme"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark">
```

Style.xml code:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#F5F5F5</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#ffe162ff</item>
</style>
```

So I read from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android) that in Lollipop "colorPrimaryDark" must change status bar color, but it doesn't work. I need to change it, bcs status bar text by default is white and with white background it became unreadable. So what I am doing wrong or I don't understand something? At the moment I use `<item name="android:statusBarColor">#000</item>` to fix my issue, but it is not cool in my opinion.

So in general, I want toolbar with white background color and readable status bar (i.e. or white background and black text, I also read that it is hard to change status bar text color, that means I can only use dark background?? Or black status bar + white default text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that when you set a `colorPrimaryDark` to a white color (or almost it) the app automatically change the color to black, try to use a darker colorPrimaryDark and it should work without additional code.
And it is **not possible** to change the text color, sorry about that.

Comment: Maybe I don't get it, but problem is that when I set colorPrimary = white and colorPrimaryDark = black it doesn't work. Am I understand right, that "colorPrimary" item for toolbar color and "colorPrimaryDark" for status bar color?

Comment: Yes, but remendar that you have to use the android material design support library.

Comment: `colorPrimaryDark` should only be a few shades darker than `colorPrimary`. It should never be the complete opposite like in your case with black/white. Go to  https://www.materialpalette.com/ and pick a design you like, you can download the finished style.xml at the bottom on the right.