# Customize the part on top of the action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'd like to know what's the name of the part on top of the action bar (where the time is displayed alongside the battery, wifi, etc), and how can its color be changed ?

Thanks !

Comment: You mean the notification bar?

Comment: public abstract void setStatusBarColor (int color) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the status bar.
Just add `colorPrimaryDark` item to your theme in `styles.xml`

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary.dark</item>
```