# How can i change status bar background color for api 11

Tags: android, material-design, statusbar

I found code for lollipop

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.actionbar));
    }
```

But how to change status bar color for minSdkVersion 11

here is a view of my gradle file.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.et.audionote"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't think you can do it below lollipop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the status bar color in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

When you want to use Material Design features below Lollipop, you can benefit from additional libraries. 
One of them on ApacheLicense is [here](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary).

Comment: while using this lib i'm getting this error 
"attribute ripplecolor has already been defined"to use this lib did i need to remove this dependincy."compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'"?

Comment: is there is any other lib for material design .. to set status bar color

Comment: As was noticed in the comments, you can't change status bar color below Lollipop. With Material Design Library you can use material design features except status bar color.

Answer (score 1):

`setStatusBarColor` Added in API level 21 android 5.0(lollipop),so you can not change StatusBarColor in pre-lollipop(android 5.0) OS version.

check [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setStatusBarColor(int))

Answer (score 0):

try with these following steps..hope you can get what do you want..i am just telling one way to change theme settings perminently.hope it'l work fine for you.

goto->tools->theme editor->
select api level and then take view of list given rightside and find like this option::
android:statusbarclor.
after changed the theme clean the project and close the emulator and restart again.
note:these settings for perimenent changes only.