# Changing the color of status bar of android while displaying splash screen using cordova-plugin-statusbar

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I can change the color of status bar in android, using the following code:

```
if (cordova.platformId == 'android') {
    StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#0974aa");
}
```

Because I have to write this code in `onDeviceReady` event handler, it will be executed after the program loaded completely(after the splash screen).

I want to have this color while displaying splash screen, too.

What can I do?

Comment: splash screen have any activity ?

Comment: @dex I can't understand what are you talking about. I'm not so expert in android.

Comment: I am asking how you are showing splash screen ? if it is activity then getwindow out of that and set status bar color. Let me know if you required code. Probably this link provide information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android

Comment: I'm using cordova's splash screen plugin to implement that. https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen