# make status bar kitkat Translucent android

Tags: android, xml

I follow some tutorial on the internet to make status bar on api19 (kitkat) transparent, but i got something like this
(`android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` **style**)
[image]

and v-19\styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/light</item>
    </style>
```

how i turn the white translucent become transparent or colored primary so it will be blended with actionbar..

Comment: You can simply call in your activity: `getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));`

Comment: ps : since Android 3.0 ....and maybe you should be a little bit more secure by `ActionBar ab = getActionBar(); if(ab!=null){}`...etc....

Comment: thanks for the feedback, but it's not work for me... still gradient black to white on status bar..

Comment: ahh, you wanted the system bar to change? Sorry, from your code I thought you want to change actionBar..for systembar see here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android

Comment: that link reference for lollipop, i want implement translucent status bar on kitkat, not completely change the color but fade from dark to transparent kitkat status bar on my app..

Comment: as the first answer suggested, possible for pre lollipop with `library support-v7-appcompat `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for myself, we need to create styles value for v19\styles.xml like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:clipToPadding">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

if we use `CoordinatorLayout` as root view we got translucent status bar and navigation bottom bar fade with `android:windowBackground` color, if we use general layout like `Linear` or `Relative` layout we got completely transparent status and navigation bar like we use `DrawerLayout` it will give same result.
adding `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in root layout will give content keep inside the application container to avoid collapse or overlapping with status bar or navigation bar.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `v-19\styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

and the following property to root layout of your xml file:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Comment: I already did, but it keep make gradiation color black to white on my status bar then my actionbar below that..

Comment: What layout have you used as root layout?

Comment: Coordinator layout mostly,,,