# How to change the status bar color to Hex color?

Tags: android, xml, statusbar

so I would like to change the status bar color in my app to the value #65BC8D.

In the previous Android Studio versions I could change it in the Theme Editor but how do I change it directly in the styles.xml?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the status bar color in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Mostly this is the `colorPrimaryDark` value if you are using the standard Material theme provided in the AppCompat themes. You can change that value to the hex value you want. E.g.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#65BC8D</item>
</style>
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes#CustomizeTheme

Also take a look at the following picture (taken from https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/changing-colorprimary-colorprimarydark-t3813991) for a reference:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The image is really usefull

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it programatically then you can use,

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
Window window = activity.getWindow();

// clear FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag:
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

// add FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS flag to the window
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

// finally change the color
window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity,R.color.my_statusbar_color));
};
```

Source - [Change status bar color in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37197235/change-status-bar-color-in-android)