# How to eliminate multiple app headers in my android app?

Tags: android, xml, layout

Noob here, I want to remove the multiple headers(?) of the app(screenshot attached). 
The blue one came by default, I was able to remove it once but now I am not sure how did it. When I removed the blue one, I made a custom one to my liking.
I'd want to know the best practice in this case, and also how to. 
I want the Logo of the app on the header(app title) along with the name. How can I do that?

[image: Current Screenshot]

Comment: put your code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `blue one` is actually `ActionBar` or now you can say `Toolbar`, and to remove that you add it to your **styles.xml** file located inside `values` folder, for e.g :

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: That seems to be working.
Is there a way by which I could add an image to it? 

Like the one I did with the second/custom Action Bar.
I'd also like to change the color of notification bar so I guess using the default ActionBar would be a better choice.

Comment: Yes you can do that, but for that you will have to set a `CustomView` to your `ActionBar` so i would suggest to go with `ToolBar`

Comment: Yes. To the ActionBar. I will just delete it.
Thanks

Comment: and just FYI, changing **StatusBar** or **NotificationBar** color will be applicable from **API 21** for more info you can see this thread on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android

Comment: @ShashankJaiswal did this work for you ?

Comment: @SatyenUdeshu Yes it did. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:theme`

```
           <activity
                android:name=".ABC"
                android:label="@string/app_name"               
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            </activity>
```