# Android status bar is the same color as Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout

I am running an android project. My toolbar and status bar are all green in my **activity_main** layout. If i change toolbar color to other color the status bar will change to the new one too.

I have an activity with **activity_hotel_detail.xml** layout. The status bar and toolbar colors are different color which is i need.

Why does the same configuration for Toolbar makes the status bar color are different?

How can i make my main_activity layout is the same one as my activity_hotel_detail layout?

I am new on android, any help thanks!

[image]

[image]
**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ViewController.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        style="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_hotel_detail.xml**

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/Blue"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        style="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:background="@color/cell">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:stretchColumns="1">
                    <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/img_description"
                        fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/test_image"
                        fresco:actualImageScaleType="fitStart"
                        android:id="@+id/hotel_image_view" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="New Text"
                        android:id="@+id/hotel_name"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:text="New Text New Text New Text New TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew Text"
                        android:id="@+id/hotel_description"/>
                <fragment
                    class="com.example.william.willhotel.ViewController.HotelDetailFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:id="@+id/fragement">
                    </fragment>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="back"
                    android:background="@color/BlueViolet"
                    android:id="@+id/back_button" />
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="next"
                    android:background="@color/DarkRed"
                    android:id="@+id/next_button" />

            </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

**EDIT**: styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/DarkRed</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/IndianRed</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/yellow</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

styles.xml(v21)

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**EDIT2** replace 'transparent1 by @color/IndianRed in styles.xml(v21) didn't work.

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/IndianRed</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**EDIT**

my activity extend from `AppCompatActivity`, i see the source code only sdk version larger than 23 can get the system theme.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

So if i run under sdk 23, the status bar appears correct as expect.

```
if (delegate.applyDayNight() && mThemeId != 0) {
            // If DayNight has been applied, we need to re-apply the theme for
            // the changes to take effect. On API 23+, we should bypass
            // setTheme(), which will no-op if the theme ID is identical to the
            // current theme ID.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                onApplyThemeResource(getTheme(), mThemeId, false);
            } else {
                setTheme(mThemeId);
            }
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android

Comment: Post your *style.xml*.

Comment: @jaydroider edited.

Comment: add Color.xml files code

Answer (score 4):

Use following code in your activity's onCreate() method

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.primary_dark));
        }
```

Where primary_dark color is your toolbar's color

Comment: Are you using following styles-v21
 <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>

Comment: Actually i am not very clear. But i pasted two files: styles.xml and styles.xml(v21)

Comment: Yeah, it is. just checked.

Comment: add this also in styles.xml(v21) 
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>

Comment: in your styles.xml change parent  to this 
"Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113886/discussion-between-krishna-meena-and-william-hu).

Comment: Hi Krishna, I will up vote your answer but your current answer is not the answer, so i will not accept it. but thank you!

Comment: But yesterday you said that this is working and BTW what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

> Add this in your `values-v21/styles.xml`.

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/IndianRed</item>
```

> Your theme should Look like this remove `Transparent`.

```
   <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/IndianRed</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This may help you**.

```
 <resources>
 <!-- inherit from the material theme -->
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
<!-- Main theme colors -->
<!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
<item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
<!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
<item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
<!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
<item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#StatusBar

**Note:** as per the google doc"the toolbar uses the 500 version of indigo, while the status bar uses the 700 version." Doc Link: https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-schemes

Answer (score 0):

```
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/cardview_dark_background</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/cardview_dark_background</item>
```

it works for me if you have multiple theme