# Change color by code at the top of action bar

Tags: android, action

Is it possible to change the color of the upper part of the action bar? As shown in the attached image

[image]

Comment: That is the status bar, not part of the action bar. In a typical Android Studio project, that is controlled by your `colorPrimaryDark` attribute on the style that you are using. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes#CustomizeTheme for more.

Comment: Yes But I want to do that by code. Because I need to change the color during the app running.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the color of the status bar in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39341818/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-status-bar-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. As @CommonsWare has said you can change the color of the **StatusBar** by editing the `colorPrimaryDark` item in your styles resource file.

[Screenshot of what it looks like in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xY8gO.png)

To change the **StatusBar** Color through Java Code, you can add the following code to your activity. Note that the Android Device must be running on `API 21` or higher.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkPurple));
}
```

Also, if you want to change the foreground text of the **StatusBar**, you can just add the following code to the `if` block. Note that the Android Device must be running on `API v23` or higher.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    // for a black color foreground text:
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
    // for a white color foreground text, just replace setSystemUiVisibility param with ~View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
}
```

Comment: Yes But I want to do that by code. Because I need to change the color during the app running.

Comment: Ok. Just edited my answer, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is the Status bar not the Action bar. However, if you want to change the statusbar color grammatically you can use `Window.setStatusBarColor()`. But the device should have `android 5.0`.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```

Should work for you.