# How to change the color of the navigation and status bar on Android Java?

Tags: java, android

It is my first time programming in android and I want to change the color of the bars, I read the documentation it seems simple but it does not work for me.
I am going to show what I add but if you need more information I will post it.

```
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.setStatusBarColor(R.color.colorWhite);
    window.setNavigationBarColor(R.color.colorWhite);
```

All it does is clarify the bar

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might like to have a look at this

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39341818/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-status-bar-in-android/39341866#:~:text=You%20can%20change%20it%20by,xml.&text=On%20API%20level%2021%2B%20you,setStatusBarColor()%20method%20from%20code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39341818/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-status-bar-in-android/39341866#:%7E:text=You%20can%20change%20it%20by,xml.&text=On%20API%20level%2021%2B%20you,setStatusBarColor()%20method%20from%20code).

It appears that you're doing fine but something is missing

Answer (score 0):

From java class:

Get color by calling resources, do this way:

```
Window window = getWindow();
window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
window.setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorSome));
```

This color can be changed from your `AppTheme` in styles.xml file. It's value can be changed from attribute `<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#yourColor</item>`

styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Their colors are available in colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

Read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes).