# How to use a resource color id with .setBackgroundDrawable

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources

I am trying to color my toolbar and status bar with two colors I have defined in the colors.xml file.

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity())
                .getSupportActionBar()
                .setBackgroundDrawable(?);


window.setStatusBarColor(?);
```

What should be put inside the brackets in order to refer to `R.color.a` and `R.color.b` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass RGB value of the color

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(248, 248, 248)));
```

To pass Resourse id

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.primary)));
```

Comment: Thanks what about .setStatusBarColor()

Comment: I dont think ActionBar has such method . For Api >=21 , refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android

Comment: I know, I'm calling it on the Window.  Thanks anyway I did it.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `setBackgroundResource()`, and not a drawable.

Comment: I can't cast that on .getSupportActionBar()

Comment: Why aren't you doing it on the toolbar?

Comment: I can't access the toolbar from the fragment. Also that question was answered, now I'm trying to understand what should I pass in .setStatusBarColor()