# Status bar with Android KitKat version fading color?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat, android-statusbar

I want to set the status bar color in Android devices with `targetSdkVersion` 19 and up. For versions with Lollipop (21) and up, I used this line of code which worked well: `getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimaryDark));` to set the status bar color to `colorPrimary` of my application. However, I noticed that when I try to use this API for SDK version 19 and below, I need to be using version 21. As a result, I looked into it and found [How to change the status bar color in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android) which would solve my problem but when I try to use the following code (Taken from the link above)

```
public static void setTaskBarColored(Activity context) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        {
            Window w = context.getWindow();
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            //status bar height
            int statusBarHeight = Utilities.getStatusBarHeight(context);

            View view = new View(context);
            view.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            view.getLayoutParams().height = statusBarHeight;
            ((ViewGroup) w.getDecorView()).addView(view);
            view.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryTaskBar));
        }
    }
```

The status bar color is set but it kind of fades from the black to the `colorPrimary` that I expect it to have. Overall I would want the status bar color to be all `colorPrimary` instead of fading from black to `colorPrimary`. Is there any way I can have the status bar to be all `colorPrimary` for android devices with KitKat downloaded? Or is there a reason why the android KitKat status bar fades from black to the colorPrimary? Either answer would help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's a feature of Android KitKat. Both status bar and navigation bar are always black on the screen edges.