# Android - most top bar name?

Tags: android

I am really curious what this bar is called and how to edit the color of it.

I got the Toolbar to the color green, but how is this blue bar above it called?
I know it is not the tool bar, i know its not an action bar, but i cant find the right name of it. Once i know the name i probably know how to change the background color of it, but i really dont know the name..

[image]

Comment: it's called status bar and color support is available on API 21 and above , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This region is called the Notifications area.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_notifications.htm

**UPDATE** It's actually called **Status Bar** while the expanded section is called Notification Area.

Some websites (see above) incorrectly call this Notification Area, and they call the resulting expanded section Notification Drawer

Comment: @Nick is correct here. Technically dragging down from the status bar will show the Notifications area, but for the purposes of Android development (and to answer the question), it's called the Status Bar.

Comment: Hey, at least I was close, why do you have to savagely downvote me? I'm trying to get to 50 reputation so I can write comments, and everyone is downvoting me like a hyperactive Squirrel on crack.

Comment: I'd recommend editing your answer so as to make it more correct, or at least clarify why you answered in the way you did. Then people will not be as inclined to downvote you.

Comment: I put the link! I referenced a source document that is incorrectly (apparently) referring to this as the "Notifications Area"

Maybe I can go to ICANN Whois and figure out the mailing address of tutorials point and mail them a polite postcard explaining their error?

Comment: @ChantellOsejo see, it shows:
```A notification is a message you can display to the user outside of your application's normal UI. When you tell the system to issue a notification, it first appears as an icon in the notification area. To see the details of the notification, the user opens the notification drawer.```

Comment: You aren't helping the situation by being sarcastic in your responses. I'm trying to help you and correct your error (this is a learning experience for you too, as you did not know the proper term either based on your answer), and hopefully get an edit out of it so you can stop being downvoted. So you can either take my advice or continue to berate people, which I assure you is unlikely to get the result you're hoping for.

Comment: Please forgive me @ChantellOsejo -- perhaps I was using humor because I find it predictable and _almost funny_ how every time I try using this site (or any Stack site), I get downvoted, criticized, pushed around and treated in a condescending way.

Answer (score 5):

That is called the Status Bar.  You can set the color by overriding your Apps style theme with:

```
android:statusBarColor="yourColor"
```

Let me know if you need help setting up the style correctly.