# Theme color on Framework7

Tags: html, html-framework-7

I have already looked at several more sites so far I have not been able to figure out how to make the color in the upper part of the app, where is the clock and the battery, using [framework7](https://framework7.io/), the same orange color in the upper right app that is in the image below. Does anyone know how to do this?

Translated from Portuguese to English - Google Translate

[image]

Comment: did you try asking the question in the Portuguese version of SO? (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: I already did, I got no response :(

Comment: Unfortunately, the question is worded as a how-to type question, which is not suitable for SO.  Feel free to read our [ask] page and edit the question to meet the requirements. Otherwise, it will be voted down and closed.  For starters, you can add a [mcve] with the issues you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about the status bar? If so, in [this page](https://framework7.io/docs/status-bar.html) you might see something relevant for you:

"In PhoneGap apps Status bar text color is always black by default. It can't be changed from Framework7, but can be customized with PhoneGap plugins like [cordova-plugin-statusbar](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar)"

Comment: I imported the status bar library into intel xdk, and enabled it in xml
<Preference name = "StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value = "true" />
    <Preference name = "StatusBarBackgroundColor" value = "#F57C00" />
    <Preference name = "StatusBarStyle" value = "lightcontent" />, worked up on android, thank you = D

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with Framework7 my friend, it is from the OS, you can check the answers here to find the best way to do it:

[How to change the status bar color in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android)