# kivy on android, change taskbar color

Tags: kivy, buildozer

Is it possible to change the taskbar color when `fullscreen` is set to `0` in `buildozer.spec` file?
I already tried changing `Window.clearcolor` value but hence taskbar is not part of `Window` when `fullscreen` is `0`, taskbar color doesn't change.
How does one do that?

Comment: You probably want to find the Android API for this setting and call it from python using pyjnius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22192691/5994041) is the answer for Java, therefore (as inclement said) you need to use [pyjnius](https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius/) to access the Java functions from Python and then wrap the code mentioned in the linked answer to something usable from Kivy.

**Example (not tested):**

```
from jnius import autoclass

WindowManager = autoclass('android.view.WindowManager')
R = autoclass('android.R')
activity = autoclass('<your.app.name>.PythonActivity').mActivity

window = activity.getWindow();
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
window.setStatusBarColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.my_statusbar_color));
```

I think only [these](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html) colors are available, but feel free to try other values. I've seen some issues with `android.R` importing in Java, so you might want to just use the raw values instead of fetching them from `android.R` module.