# Background image of screen size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-activity, android-designer

I have a problem with the background image of my login activity.
I can't remove the white bar at the top of the background image...
Someone can help me?

In preview:

[image]

In my smartphone:

[image]

Here is my Relative Layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/login_background"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.project.main.application.view.activity.Av_Login">
```

Comment: call `getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);` in onCreate of your activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below line of code

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < MINIMUM_API_LEVEL) {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        } else {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
```

Comment: Your condition doesn't work but i change to: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) and it works, THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 0):

add Main Activity in onCreate before setContentView();

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

manifest activity add fullscreen theme

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivty"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The status bar color matches to the colorPrimaryDark in your styles.xml (white in your case).

If you want to change this read this answer : [How to change the status bar color in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

There is one more solution, but API level 19 is the limitation as well,
`windowTranslucentStatus` property.

**style(v19)**

```
<!-- Considering AppTheme as your app's theme -->
<style name="AppTheme.Trans" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

Now apply that theme to your `<activity>` element in `manifest`

```
<activity
     android:name=".ui.login.SplashActivity"
     android:screenOrientation="portrait"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Trans"
     android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
```