# Android Immersive Mode - custom color

Tags: java, android

I have enabled `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY` in my app but it seems that the default behavior makes the navigation and notification bar transparent. Is there any way to set the custom color to status bar and navigation bar (or retain system default which is black?)

[image: immersive mode with custom color]

Comment: I assume you already have tried [`statusBarColor`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22192691/1083957), right?

Comment: I have tried that but it does not work for API 19. It only sets statusbar color not the navigation

Comment: Maybe this [page](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html) can help you.

Comment: I have setup the theme as per the guidelines and it works perfectly if I dont use Immersive mode. The colors are lost only in Immersive mode