# How find and change OS Notification bar color?

Tags: android, operating-system, android-notification-bar, android-statusbar

My question is, how can I change the default system notification bar colors?
like other customize OS theme apps do.
is there for example a systemColor.xml that we can change it using modify-system-setting-permission ?
Thanks in advance.

Note: I don't wanna change status bar only in my application , I wanna for example develop a theme editor for whole OS of phone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the status bar color in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android)

Comment: @nano no, I don't wanna do it in my app only, I wanna change it in whole of OS! for example I wanna develop a theme editor