# How to change the color of above Toolbar?

Tags: android, toolbar

I am new in android development and I do not know that what it is actually called(Above space of Toolbar which is shown in the image below or where time and battery sign is showing.)  and I want to fill custom color on it so please tell me how to fill the color on it.
[image]
thank you...

Below is my XML file

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#eee">
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.devbhoomimedia.maangal.ProfilesActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:titleTextColor="#ffffff"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            app:tabTextColor="#ffffff"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            android:background="#2f6b00"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_nevigation"
    app:itemTextAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"/>
```

Comment: In res there is value folder in that colors.xml file will be there .In that colorPrimaryDark  color is there.Change the color code there.It will help you to change the color

Comment: Thank you @R.Anjali It's also working for me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the status bar color in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View above the Toolbar is officially know as `status bar` in android and to change color of `status bar` check out the answer of this question [How to change the status bar color in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android)

Answer (score 3):

Try below :

Go to app -> res -> value -> colors.xml - change `colorPrimaryDark` color

```
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#030239</color>
```

or,

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_secondary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
     <!---Below is the code for status bar color------>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/color_secondary</item>
</style>
```

or,

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
Window window = getWindow();
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
window.setStatusBarColor(Color.RED);
}
```

Comment: Let check him @sudha, He is not replying ?

Comment: I was offline that's why I din reply. now let me check

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for API Level 21 and above: 
**Place this is your values-v21/styles.xml**
-> The space on the top of toolbar is called StatusBar.

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_secondary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/color_primary</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Check popular answer At [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android).

*Happy Coding...*