# How to make Android status bar light in Flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

As the title suggests, this is about Flutter.

Is there any way to switch Android status bar to light mode so that the icons in status bar show up dark? See picture for example.

I tried following possible solutions but none of them worked -

```
// main.dart
appBar: new AppBar(
      brightness: Brightness.light,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    ),

// MainActivity.kt
// Following 2 lines do change the color of status and nav bars
window.statusBarColor = 0x00000000
window.navigationBarColor = 0x00000000

// This seems to have no effect. Icons are still white.
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
```

[image]

---

#### UPDATE

The support for this is in works - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17231

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the status bar color in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android)

Comment: You do this with your AndroidManifest, not in dart code

Comment: How do you do this in the AndroidManifest? Also the question that was marked as possible duplicate of is about status bar color. This question is NOT about status bar color. Please note `<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>` is different than `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/whatever</item>`

Comment: I am able to change status bar color from Dart. It is very much possible to have it set as default darker version of appbar color from Dart. But I am NOT able to change it to light so that icons in it are dark.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/7347#issuecomment-377071330 might be helpful

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Nop, it's not the same. I am not asking about status bar color. I am asking about status bar mode - dark or light. In light mode, icons automatically turn dark to contrast it. It was introduced with Android v23 as `<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>`

Comment: Flutter doesn't use Andtoid API, it renders everything by itself.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer That is a wrong answer. Yes flutter does render things inside an app but system bars are not flutter rendered. This support is in fact being added. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17231

Comment: During launch in splash screen the status and navigation bar still can't be set to the light mode. Changing the appearance after the splash screen is not desirable and interrupts the user experience. Why is it not possible to change the mode with <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item> in the main activtiy?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Flutter team have now added support for light/dark status bar control. To add, import this:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

Then add this in your App's build function:

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.copyWith(
  statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark
));
```

Comment: Anyway to do this during the splash screen launch? (I guess not)

Answer (score 2):

Just additional notes:

To change the status bar icon to dark put the following code

```
StatusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light
```

and add brightness in appbar.

```
appBar: AppBar(  
brightness: Brightness.light, )
```

if you would like to use white bg on status bar, then change to .light so that icon can be dark, and .dark for darker status bar with white icon