# Flutter - How to set status bar color when AppBar not present

Tags: dart, flutter, statusbar

How to set status bar color when AppBar not present.

I have tried this but not working.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark);
    return new Scaffold(
        body: new Container(
        color: UniQueryColors.colorBackground,
        child: new ListView.builder(
           itemCount: 7,
           itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
             if (index == 0){
               return addTopInfoSection();
             }
           },
        ),
       ),
    );
}
```

**Output look like this:**

[image]

Comment: how did you managed the space of the statusbar, preventing the content from overlapping?

Comment: @Hannes.T Use my above code

Comment: I don't quit get where you add that extra padding/margin that your blue container doesn't overlap

Comment: @Hannes.T For Android, it's by default. For iOS, I think you might have to check for `MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top`.

Comment: you can wrap your content in a SafeArea widget @Hannes.T

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59949734/8555008 check this out

Answer (score 139, accepted):

First, import `services` package:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

Next, simply put this in the **build function** of your App:

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  statusBarColor: Colors.blue, //or set color with: Color(0xFF0000FF)
));
```

Additionally, you can set useful properties like: `statusBarIconBrightness`, `systemNavigationBarColor` or `systemNavigationBarDividerColor`

---

If you prefer a more **flutter/widget** way of doing the same thing, consider using the `AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>` widget.

The `value:` property can be set to a `SystemUiOverlayStyle()` object containing the same properties as shown above.

---

**For more infos, head over to the [API Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemChrome/setSystemUIOverlayStyle.html)**

Comment: Add import statement: `import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`

Comment: This doesn't work well with navigation, or in some situation doesn't seem to work at all. I've add better results with `Jordy Sinke`'s answer, which also feels more fluttery.

Comment: Someone mentioned this only works for android and not ios. T/F ?

Comment: Does this work programatically? like when I/the user switch the theme between light and dark mode? Some of these options I noticed only works on rebuilds.

Comment: statusBarColor is only honored in Android version M and greater, no iOS.

Comment: Use annotatedregion, this solution is better because it manages automatically

Answer (score 101):

If you take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/af3cdb33dab6092c47453b6cdcb790514caf8e6b/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app_bar.dart) of AppBar, you can see they use an AnnotatedRegion widget. AnnotedRegion widget gives you more control on System overlay style. This is a more fluttery way to configure the system styles when an app bar is not used.

From my understanding, this widget automatically sets the statusbar/navigationbar color when the widget wrapped in it gets overlaid by the statusbar/navigationbar.

You can wrap your widget like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

...    

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
      body: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
         value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,                
         child: ...,
      ),
   );
}
```

**For more information about AnnotatedRegion widget head over to the [API Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemChrome/setSystemUIOverlayStyle.html)**

Comment: this should be the accepted answer because it aligns with how the framework handles it

Comment: Agreed - it also handles page transitions back, if the previous page used a different value

Comment: Also, if I have an App with Dark/Light Theme, I use this code in value:

**(Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark)
            ? SystemUiOverlayStyle.light
            : SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark**

Comment: Replace this to change the status bar color `value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(
          statusBarColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        )`

Comment: app seems more lagging with this method

Comment: this is should be selected as top answer.

Answer (score 15):

As the solution is already mentioned, I am implementing it in a different approach. The approach followed is removing **AppBar** and changing the color of the status bar using **Container** widget.

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Test',
      home: Scaffold(
        primary: true,
        appBar: EmptyAppBar(),
        body: MyScaffold(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(
        'Test',
      ),
    );
  }
}

class EmptyAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.black,
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size(0.0, 0.0);
}
```

- Here I am using **EmptyAppBar** class for removing the **AppBar** which is by default present in **Scaffold**
- In **EmptyAppBar** class we can choose the required color in the container widget.
- After that, you have your own custom **MyScaffold** class for creating your widgets. In my code, I've created a text.

Reference: [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/4518#issuecomment-424298638)

Comment: I found this to be the best solution for an app that combines screens with and without an `AppBar`. The `SystemUiOverlayStyle` approach overrides the `AppBar` settings and does not reset when leaving the screen.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, thank you

Comment: This answer saved my day.

Answer (score 8):

While searching for SystemChrome I found this: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/SystemChrome/setSystemUIOverlayStyle.html

Right above the sample code is a paragraph about `AppBar.brightness`.

You should should be able to add an AppBar like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark);
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text('Nice title!'),
            brightness: Brightness.light,
        ),
        body: new Container(
        color: UniQueryColors.colorBackground,
        child: new ListView.builder(
           itemCount: 7,
           itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
             if (index == 0){
               return addTopInfoSection();
             }
           },
        ),
       ),
    );
}
```

Heres info about the [Brightness](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/Brightness-class.html)

Answer (score 7):

On Android, add the following to onCreate in **MainActivity.java**, after the call to super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

> getWindow().setStatusBarColor(0x00000000);

or you can use the the [flutter_statusbarcolor](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_statusbarcolor#-readme-tab-) plugin

```
   changeStatusColor(Color color) async {
    try {
      await FlutterStatusbarcolor.setStatusBarColor(color);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

[Sample project](https://github.com/mchome/flutter_statusbarcolor/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I will check them.

Answer (score 7):

you should solve this question in two ways:

1. you did not set appBar then you just write in this way:

```dart
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.copyWith(
  statusBarColor: Colors.black, 
));
```

or

```dart
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(
  statusBarColor: Colors.white, 
));
```

2. you always set appBar so you should set appBar but not upon code:

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    brightness: Brightness.light,
  )
)
```

or

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks ... In my case it worked when I use SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark  with statusBarColor: Colors.white

Comment: Thank you sir. `brightness: Brightness.dark` works.

Comment: Well explained, saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
AppBar(
  systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.orange),
)
```

or

```dart
AppBar(
  backgroundColor: Colors.red, // Status bar color
  brightness: Brightness.light, // Status bar brightness
)
```

Comment: what exactly does `backwardsCompatibility` do?

Comment: @Stuck `backwardsCompatibility` will be removed in future and its default value will be set to `false` which I just did. Setting it `true` doesn't allow `systemOverlayStyle` property to work.

Comment: I found the description: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/backwardsCompatibility.html

Comment: outdated backward comp.

Comment: @petrasJ Yes, it was going to be deprecated as I've mentioned in the comment before.

Answer (score 5):

I tried many methods but they didn’t work. And i found another method, use safeArea ,AnnotatedRegion and Scaffold

```
AnnotatedRegion(
  // status icon and text color, dark:black  light:white
  value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark,
  child: Scaffold(
     // statusbar color
     backgroundColor: Colors.white,
     body : SafeArea(****)
  )
}
```

The code implements the white status bar and black text

Answer (score 4):

The status bar colour is rendered by the Android system. Whether that can be set from Flutter or not is up for debate: [How to make Android status bar light in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49179175/how-to-make-android-status-bar-light-in-flutter)

What you can do however, is change the status bar colour in the Android specific code by editing the theme: [How to change the status bar color in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android)

For iOS you'll have to see their documentation - I'm not familiar with the platform.

There are in fact two Dart libraries, one for setting the [light/dark theme of the statusbar](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_statusbarcolor) and the other for [setting the colour](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_statusbarcolor). I haven't used either, but clearly someone else has had the same issue you're facing and ended up developing their own package.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I will check them.

Answer (score 4):

If you dont want to use app bar, then

```
appBar: AppBar(
      elevation: 0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white, # status bar color
      toolbarHeight: 0,
      brightness: Brightness.light # or Brightness.dark
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
    value: const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.green, // Color of you choice
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
    ),
    child: Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(child: Text("Center Text")),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new Scaffold(
        body: new Container(
            color: UniQueryColors.colorBackground,

    /* Wrapping ListView.builder with MediaQuery.removePadding() removes the default padding of the ListView.builder() and the status bar takes the color of the app background */

        child: MediaQuery.removePadding(
         removeTop: true,
         context: context,
        child: ListView.builder(
           itemCount: 7,
           itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
             if (index == 0){
               return addTopInfoSection();
             }
           },
        ),
       ),
      ),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following in your main function to change the status bar color for all the views/screens. This will work even without an app bar.

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark, // this will change the brightness of the icons
  statusBarColor: Colors.white, // or any color you want
));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are implementing dark and light theme, it can be tricky and you don't want the app bar, here is a work around i implemented

```
appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 0.0,
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
```

Implement an empty `appBar`, and on your `ThemeData` implement like below, remember to state `AppBar` background color

```
theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: GoogleFonts.poppins().fontFamily,
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 226, 226, 226),
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 226, 226, 226),
        ),
        colorScheme: const ColorScheme(
          background: Color.fromARGB(255, 226, 226, 226),
          onBackground: Color.fromARGB(255, 217, 217, 217),
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 166, 133),
          onPrimary: Color.fromARGB(255, 248, 248, 248),
          secondary: Color.fromARGB(255, 100, 157, 0),
          onSecondary: Colors.white,
          error: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
          onError: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 0),
          surface: Color.fromARGB(255, 222, 222, 222),
          onSurface: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
          onSurfaceVariant: Color.fromARGB(255, 215, 215, 215),
          surfaceVariant: Color.fromARGB(255, 241, 241, 241),
          outline: Color.fromARGB(255, 122, 122, 122),
          tertiary: Color.fromARGB(255, 214, 161, 0)
        )
      ),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: GoogleFonts.tajawal().fontFamily,
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 18, 18),
          appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
            backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 18, 18),
          ),
        colorScheme: const ColorScheme(
          background: Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 18, 18),
          onBackground: Color.fromARGB(255, 49, 49, 49),
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
          primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 255, 204),
          onPrimary: Colors.black,
          secondary: Color.fromARGB(255, 178, 255, 44),
          onSecondary: Colors.white,
          error: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
          onError: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 0),
          surface: Color.fromARGB(255, 37, 37, 37),
          onSurface: Colors.white,
          onSurfaceVariant: Color.fromARGB(255, 55, 55, 55),
          surfaceVariant: Color.fromARGB(255, 34, 34, 34),
          outline: Color.fromARGB(255, 158, 158, 158),
          tertiary: Colors.amber
        )
      ),
      themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `EmptyAppBar`, with some code for restoring color as in `AppBar`.

```
class EmptyAppBar  extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  static const double _defaultElevation = 4.0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    final AppBarTheme appBarTheme = AppBarTheme.of(context);
    final Brightness brightness = appBarTheme.brightness
        ?? themeData.primaryColorBrightness;
    final SystemUiOverlayStyle overlayStyle = brightness == Brightness.dark
        ? SystemUiOverlayStyle.light
        : SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark;

    return Semantics(
      container: true,
      child: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
        value: overlayStyle,
        child: Material(
          color: appBarTheme.color
              ?? themeData.primaryColor,
          elevation: appBarTheme.elevation
              ?? _defaultElevation,
          child: Semantics(
            explicitChildNodes: true,
            child: Container(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size(0.0,0.0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this best status bar like default material design theme without AppBar()

```
 Container(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, height: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top, color: Theme.of(context).accentColor)
```

Comment: This is just perfect answer and helped me a lot. Each view can have different statusbar colors and we don't need to worry why some specific view uses color, while it isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this to your build function, or main function.

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.light);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have to add this if you want to use as default template in the MaterialApp Theme :

```
appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(brightness: Brightness.light)
```

Result will be like this :

```
return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(brightness: Brightness.light),  <========
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: ...,
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying many methods, I found below method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61025717/11675817).

If you are using `SafeArea` use this method:

```
Scaffold(
 body: Container(
    color: Colors.white, // your desire status bar color
    child: SafeArea(child: CHILD),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `SystemUiOverlayStyle`

```
 Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              elevation: 0.0,
              systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
                statusBarColor: Colors.white,
                statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark,
                statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
              )),
          body:.....
```

Comment: this is not working anymore properly

Answer (score -2):

Here You can use flutter flutter_statusbar_manager 1.0.2 lib

Flutter Statusbar Manager, lets you control the status bar color, style (theme), visibility, and translucent properties across iOS and Android. With some added bonus for Android to control the Navigation Bar.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_statusbar_manager/flutter_statusbar_manager.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp();

  factory MyApp.forDesignTime() {
    // TODO: add arguments
    return new MyApp();
  }

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  double _statusBarHeight = 0.0;
  bool _statusBarColorAnimated = false;
  Color _statusBarColor = Colors.black;
  double _statusBarOpacity = 1.0;
  bool _statusBarHidden = false;
  StatusBarAnimation _statusBarAnimation = StatusBarAnimation.NONE;
  StatusBarStyle _statusBarStyle = StatusBarStyle.DEFAULT;
  bool _statusBarTranslucent = false;
  bool _loadingIndicator = false;
  bool _fullscreenMode = false;

  bool _navBarColorAnimated = false;
  Color _navBarColor = Colors.black;
  NavigationBarStyle _navBarStyle = NavigationBarStyle.DEFAULT;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
  }

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    double statusBarHeight;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      statusBarHeight = await FlutterStatusbarManager.getHeight;
    } on PlatformException {
      statusBarHeight = 0.0;
    }
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _statusBarHeight = statusBarHeight;
    });
  }

  Widget renderTitle(String text) {
    final textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
    return Text(text, style: textStyle);
  }

  void colorBarChanged(Color val) {
    this.setState(() {
      _statusBarColor = val;
    });
    updateStatusBar();
  }

  void updateStatusBar() {
    FlutterStatusbarManager.setColor(
        _statusBarColor.withOpacity(_statusBarOpacity),
        animated: _statusBarColorAnimated);
  }

  void statusBarAnimationChanged(StatusBarAnimation val) {
    this.setState(() {
      _statusBarAnimation = val;
    });
  }

  void statusBarStyleChanged(StatusBarStyle val) {
    this.setState(() {
      _statusBarStyle = val;
    });
    FlutterStatusbarManager.setStyle(val);
  }

  void colorNavBarChanged(Color val) {
    this.setState(() {
      _navBarColor = val;
    });
    updateNavBar();
  }

  void updateNavBar() {
    FlutterStatusbarManager.setNavigationBarColor(_navBarColor,
        animated: _navBarColorAnimated);
  }

  void navigationBarStyleChanged(NavigationBarStyle val) {
    this.setState(() {
      _navBarStyle = val;
    });
    FlutterStatusbarManager.setNavigationBarStyle(val);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: const Text('Statusbar Manager example'),
        ),
        body: new Container(
          child: new Scrollbar(
            child: new ListView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0, horizontal: 20.0),
              children: <Widget>[
                renderTitle("Status Bar Height: $_statusBarHeight"),
                Divider(height: 25.0),
                renderTitle("Status Bar Color:"),
                SwitchListTile(
                  value: _statusBarColorAnimated,
                  title: new Text("Animated:"),
                  onChanged: (bool value) {
                    this.setState(() {
                      _statusBarColorAnimated = value;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                Text("Color:"),
                RadioListTile(
                    value: Colors.black,
                    title: Text("Black"),
                    onChanged: colorBarChanged,
                    dense: true,
                    groupValue: _statusBarColor),
                RadioListTile(
                    value: Colors.orange,
                    title: Text("Orange"),
                    onChanged: colorBarChanged,
                    dense: true,
                    groupValue: _statusBarColor),
                RadioListTile(
                    value: Colors.greenAccent,
                    title: Text("Green"),
                    onChanged: colorBarChanged,
                    dense: true,
                    groupValue: _statusBarColor),
                RadioListTile(
                    value: Colors.white30,
                    title: Text("White"),
                    onChanged: colorBarChanged,
                    dense: true,
                    groupValue: _statusBarColor),
                Text("Opacity:"),
                Slider(
                  value: _statusBarOpacity,
                  min: 0.0,
                  max: 1.0,
                  onChanged: (double val) {
                    this.setState(() {
                      _statusBarOpacity = val;
                    });
                    updateStatusBar();
                  },
                ),
                Divider(height: 25.0),
                renderTitle("Status Bar Hidden:"),
                SwitchListTile(
                  title: new Text("Hidden:"),
                  value: _statusBarHidden,
                  onChanged: (bool val) {
                    this.setState(() {
                      _statusBarHidden = val;
                    });
                    FlutterStatusbarManager.setHidden(_statusBarHidden,
                        animation: _statusBarAnimation);
                  },
                ),
                Text("Animation:"),
                RadioListTile(
                    value: StatusBarAnimation.NONE,
                    title: Text("NONE"),
                    onChanged: statusBarAnimationChanged,
                    dense: true,
                    groupValue: _statusBarAnimation),
                RadioListTile(
                    value: StatusBarAnimation.FADE,
                    title: Text("FADE"),
                    onChanged: statusBarAnimationChanged,
                    dense: true,
                    groupValue: _statusBarAnimation),
                RadioListTile(
                    value: StatusBarAnimation.SLIDE,
                    title: Text("SLIDE"),
                    onChanged: statusBarAnimationChanged,
                    dense: true,
                    groupValue: _statusBarAnimation),
                Divider(height: 25.0),
                renderTitle("Status Bar Style:"),
                RadioListTile(
                    value: StatusBarStyle.DEFAULT,
                    title: Text("DEFAULT"),
                    onChanged: statusBarStyleChanged,
                    dense: true,
                    groupValue: _statusBarStyle),
                RadioListTile(
                    value: StatusBarStyle.LIGHT_CONTENT,
                    title: Text("LIGHT_CONTENT"),
                    onChanged: statusBarStyleChanged,
                    dense: true,
                    groupValue: _statusBarStyle),
                RadioListTile(
                    value: StatusBarStyle.DARK_CONTENT,
                    title: Text("DARK_CONTENT"),
                    onChanged: statusBarStyleChanged,
                    dense: true,
                    groupValue: _statusBarStyle),
                Divider(height: 25.0),
                renderTitle("Status Bar Translucent:"),
                SwitchListTile(
                  title: new Text("Translucent:"),
                  value: _statusBarTranslucent,
                  onChanged: (bool val) {
                    this.setState(() {
                      _statusBarTranslucent = val;
                    });
                    FlutterStatusbarManager
                        .setTranslucent(_statusBarTranslucent);
                  },
                ),
                Divider(height: 25.0),
                renderTitle("Status Bar Activity Indicator:"),
                SwitchListTile(
                  title: new Text("Indicator:"),
                  value: _loadingIndicator,
                  onChanged: (bool val) {
                    this.setState(() {
                      _loadingIndicator = val;
                    });
                    FlutterStatusbarManager
                        .setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible(_loadingIndicator);
                  },
                ),
                Divider(height: 25.0),
                renderTitle("Navigation Bar Color:"),
                SwitchListTile(
                  value: _navBarColorAnimated,
                  title: new Text("Animated:"),
                  onChanged: (bool value) {
                    this.setState(() {
                      _navBarColorAnimated = value;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                Text("Color:"),
                RadioListTile(
                    value: Colors.black,
                    title: Text("Black"),
                    onChanged: colorNavBarChanged,
                    dense: true,
                    groupValue: _navBarColor),
                RadioListTile(
                    value: Colors.orange,
                    title: Text("Orange"),
                    onChanged: colorNavBarChanged,
                    dense: true,
                    groupValue: _navBarColor),
                RadioListTile(
                    value: Colors.greenAccent,
                    title: Text("Green"),
                    onChanged: colorNavBarChanged,
                    dense: true,
                    groupValue: _navBarColor),
                RadioListTile(
                    value: Colors.white12,
                    title: Text("white"),
                    onChanged: colorNavBarChanged,
                    dense: true,
                    groupValue: _navBarColor),
                Divider(height: 25.0),
                renderTitle("Navigation Bar Style:"),
                RadioListTile(
                    value: NavigationBarStyle.DEFAULT,
                    title: Text("DEFAULT"),
                    onChanged: navigationBarStyleChanged,
                    dense: true,
                    groupValue: _navBarStyle),
                RadioListTile(
                    value: NavigationBarStyle.LIGHT,
                    title: Text("LIGHT"),
                    onChanged: navigationBarStyleChanged,
                    dense: true,
                    groupValue: _navBarStyle),
                RadioListTile(
                    value: NavigationBarStyle.DARK,
                    title: Text("DARK"),
                    onChanged: navigationBarStyleChanged,
                    dense: true,
                    groupValue: _navBarStyle),
                Divider(height: 25.0),
                renderTitle("Fullscreen mode:"),
                SwitchListTile(
                  title: new Text("Fullscreen:"),
                  value: _fullscreenMode,
                  onChanged: (bool val) {
                    this.setState(() {
                      _fullscreenMode = val;
                    });
                    FlutterStatusbarManager.setFullscreen(_fullscreenMode);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```