# Flutter IphoneX status bar color without app Bar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a case where I do not want the app bar in my application , the problem is if I remove the app bar the status bar is coming in default color and there is no property in scaffolding to update status bar color , there is no effect of wrapping Body in safe are or not the status bar always stays

Sample Code

```
return Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
```

Comment: It had not effect on layout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter - How to set status bar color when AppBar not present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50501799/flutter-how-to-set-status-bar-color-when-appbar-not-present)

Answer (score 4):

You can change the color of the status bar by making AppBar invisible. With `PreferredSize` we can set the Height of AppBar to 0 and set the `backgroundColor` property for status bar color.

```
appBar: PreferredSize(child: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      elevation: 0.0,
    ),
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0.0)
  )
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use a scaffold `Scaffold`, you can change this widget to change the text/icon color of the status bar:

```
AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
  value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light, // or dark
  child: <your page>,
)
```

To change the background color, use a `Container` or `DecoratedBox`.

You can get the height of the status bar from `MediaQuery.of(context).padding`.

Comment: I want material app with scaffold