# How to enable Light Mode for Status and Navigation Bar for Flutter Android from Launch on

Tags: android, flutter

I want to enable the light mode for the status and navigation bar in Flutter Android starting from launch, so that the icons are dark. I can change the background color of both in the Main Activity, but setting to light mode with `window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR` seems to have no effect and the icons remain white.

Watch it here:

[image]

The code looks like this:

**styles.xml**

```
   <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    </style>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
            window.statusBarColor = Color.parseColor("#ffffff")
            window.navigationBarColor = Color.parseColor("#ffffff")
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
            window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 28) {
            window.navigationBarDividerColor = Color.parseColor("#eeeeee")
        }

    }
}
```

---

I know that we can set it with the Flutter API with `SystemChrome` as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49179175/how-to-make-android-status-bar-light-in-flutter), but that doesn't affect the status and navigation bar during launch.

Watch it here:

[image]