# can I use different themes on different activity screens

Tags: android

on my create screen, the nav bar is black instead of this pinky colour I made it to be. I don't really know what's the issue

styles.xml

```
    <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>


    <style name="CreateTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorCreate</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

manifest code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.supermarketaislefinder">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".create"
            android:theme="@style/CreateTheme"/>

        <activity android:name=".view" />
        <activity android:name=".settings"></activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I tried taking android:theme"@style/AppTheme" and putting it under the  tag but no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean the toolbar (bar at the top of screen) when you say nav bar. By default, the toolbar color is the same as `colorPrimary` if the toolbar was generated for you. Check that the toolbar has `android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"` inside of it then change the primary color with your custom color.

```
<style name="CreateTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorCreate</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Comment: thank you, that worked. I was also wondering how to change the colour of the  bar right at the top which shows the time, wifi, signal etc. On my phone , it's just the normal grey colour.

Comment: @crazyCoderN The bar you're referring to is called the status bar. If your minimum SDK is at least 21 then you should be able to use `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorCreate</item>`. Check out [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android)

Comment: thanks for that. My phones sdk is 16. Is it possible to make it so you can still run the app on a phone with an sdk less than 21 but it won't show the status bar colour? and you can still run it on a phone with a sdk higher than 21 and it'll show the colour?

Comment: @crazyCoderN I think you can't change the status bar color for SDK lower than 21 so you don't have to worry about it. But I recommend creating a separate `styles.xml` for min SDK >= 21. To do so, create a folder called `values-v21` inside `res` and put a new `styles.xml` inside. By separating the styles, you can use version-specific style features like the `statusBarColor`.