# Xamarin.Forms: Se tStatus Bar Color on android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am tryingo to set the status bar color on Android version of my xamarin forms project.

using:

```
     Window.SetStatusBarColor(Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.colorPrimary));
```

I have achieved the expected color, but instruction seem deprecated.

To avoid future crashed, How I can actualice the instruction?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're doing right, the deprecated method is `Resources.GetColor`, you can just do it this way `Window.SetStatusBarColor(Resource.Color.colorPrimary);`

Comment: Unknown identifier Resources

Answer (score 1):

you can change the color of the status bar using the new window.setStatusBarColor method introduced in API level 21.

Changing the color of status bar also requires setting two additional flags on the Window; you need to add the **FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS** flag and clear the **FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS** flag.

```
Window window = activity.getWindow();

        // clear FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag:
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

        // add FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS flag to the window
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

        // finally change the color
        window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.my_statusbar_color));
```

Here is the same thread that you can take a look:
[How to change the status bar color in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the color of your statusbar by applying color in your Styles.xml file, located under Resources -> values Folder.

```
<!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1eb6ed</item>
```

Place this and it should work.
Hope this may help you.