# color of status bar in Android Studio

Tags: android, statusbar

I am Struggling to change the color of the status bar for each activity.

I have tried the create theme and style listed in posts on this site to no avail.

How can I make each activity have a status bar of different color?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android)

Comment: Have you tried to change the toolbar background?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the status bar color in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android)

Comment: Thank you... It doesn't show change inside android studio but does effect the color change on my device. @0X0cosugar ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it by setting the `android:statusBarColor` or `android:colorPrimaryDark` attribute of the style you're using for your app in `styles.xml`.

(`android:statusBarColor` inherits the value of `android:colorPrimaryDark` by default)

For example (since we're using an `AppCompat` theme here, the android namespace is omitted):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/your_custom_color</item>
</style>
```

On API level 21+ you can also use the `Window.setStatusBarColor()` method from code.