# Android - How to change the status bar color of the NavigationView?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-styles, android-navigationview, android-statusbar

I've tried everything I can to achieve this feature but failed, "drawerLayout.setStatusBarBackground()" doesn't work, "android:windowTranslucentStatus:true" doen't work.

Here, first image is all I can do now, and the second one is the desired effect:

[All I can do now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ri3C.png)

[Desired effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLjK6.png)

Thank you so much.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm asking the Navigation Drawer Status Bar (when you slide out, the topmost bar), not the default Status Bar (although they are the same...but I want to change the color for certain part of it)

Comment: Did you able to figure it out? All i know is that behavior is distinct to `NavigationView`  if you use `FrameLayout` instead, you can achieve this effect using translucent status and `android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds`

you have to handle insets manually tho.

Answer (score 6):

Problem is that `NavigationView` extends `ScrimInsetsFrameLayout` which listens window insets changes and adds dim line to the layout.

The same`ScrimInsetsFrameLayout` has styleable property `insetForeground` at least in `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07`

so if you use:

```
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/transparent</item>
```

You only need to set that `insetForeground` to `@color/transparent`

For example:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:insetForeground="@color/transparent"/>
```

**Warning:**
This will not work if you set `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`.

**Caution:** 
Using this approach means that you have to manage your insets manually since you are using translucent status and not fitting system windws.