# How to set Android status bar background color to white

Tags: android, themes

What theme should I use in my Android app to make my status bar white color like the one in Instagram.

Im using `Theme.Appcompat.Light` as my theme.

This is my colors.xml:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<resources>
    <color name="primaryColor">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="primaryLightColor">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="primaryDarkColor">#cccccc</color>
    <color name="secondaryColor">#3f51b5</color>
    <color name="secondaryLightColor">#757de8</color>
    <color name="secondaryDarkColor">#002984</color>
    <color name="primaryTextColor">#000000</color>
    <color name="secondaryTextColor">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

Instagram style:

[image: Instagram style]

My app:

[image: My app]

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24997241

Answer (score 0):

Actually `colorPrimaryDark` is responsible for status bar color(but not only).

From 23 SDK you could directly set status bar color.

```
public void setStatusBarColor(final int color) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(color);
    }
}
```