# Android SDK version migration UI issue

Tags: android

I'm trying to migrate one application from old Android SDK 23 to 28. The migration went successfully except one thing: the most upper bar (not sure how it is called in Android and looks it is not part of application) changed its color from black (in SDK 23) to main background color (see attachment). How can change its color back to black.
Apart SDK version change I have changed version of com.android.support:appcompat-v7 and com.android.support:design to version "28.0.0"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of it is: "Status Bar"

> Android 5.0 Lollipop introduced Material Design theme which
>   automatically colors the status bar based on the `colorPrimaryDark`
>   value of the theme.
>
> This is supported on device pre-lollipop thanks to the library
>   support-v7-appcompat starting from version 21. [Blogpost about support
>   appcompat v21 from Chris Banes](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24997241/4853835