# Where do I find the styles.xml file in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-styles

I have a very simple application that runs an html file. I really want to change the color of the status bar, because the standard top and bottom in black is horrible for the color palette of the page shown. I have no idea about Android and I can't start learning now, but I tried to follow the answers, as in this question here at Stack Overflow: [How to change the status bar color in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android). However, I can't even find the styles.xml file that is indicated to put the parameters inside. I tried to create the "value" folder with the styles.xml file inside, but it only corrupted the app, as I imagined it would happen.

This is how the file tree of my app (generated by the Website to APK Builder) is seen:

[image: tree of files]

What do I do to accomplish this?

Note: I tried the edits through Android Studio.

For more details, here's the .apk: [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Yyvjq2_VbjTOAhVg7nRHkGgGcx-pGxNe)

Answer (score 9):

Change project structure to Android.

Follow below image

[image]

Now getting structure like below Image:

[image]

Here is style.xml file present under `res->values`

If not getting style.xml file, then Create new file `res->values->New->Value Resource file`

[image]

Comment: heey, thanks for answering! the "Android" option isn't shown :/ look: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tGfK3TmGGSnDwiXgOwY2vb0pXOChxxZC

Comment: I think your Gradle project is not properly sync. Please make sure your gradle project sync properly

Answer (score 9):

You don't need a styles.xml file in the new Android Studio. Go to your project file view: Res>Values>Themes folder.

Open themes.xml file change actionbar.

[android studio live example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbcON.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in your resource directory

> res/values/styles.xml

Comment: Hello Emmanuel. Did you see my screenshot? There's no this file inside "res"

Comment: Then you will have to create it yourself.

Comment: when i do this the apk gets corrupted. I believe there is something more that needs to be done, but I really don't understand anything, that's why I'm asking for help

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on res - new - package - write the name of package as values - in the drop down of folder type, select values - ok.
2. The values folder is created!
3. Right click on values package - new - Android Resource Xml file - write name as styles in the name section - Ok.

Comment: doesn't show the option to create a package, look https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EKBtelYa0IxWT61ZgDC6Qq5ESTm5by46

Comment: When u right click on res and then new...what option u get? Can u see package?

Comment: I see the follow options: File, Stratch File, Directory, C++ Class, C/C+ Source File, C/C++ Header File, Kotlin Script, Kotlin Worksheet, Gradle Kotlin DSL Build Script, Gradle Kotlin DSL Settings, Edit File Templates..., EditorConfig File, Resource Bundle. I cant see package :/